# How to write C program without 'main'?

Tags: c, assembly

How to write C program without using Main...!
When I'm learning how to write ASM file by for a simple C file [of length 3 lines], I got this doubt.
I assembly file I used preamble and post ambles, at function.

Comment: Have a look at: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113731/is-a-main-required-for-a-c-program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113731/is-a-main-required-for-a-c-program), search for similar topics in stackoverflow, there are a lot of them

Answer (score 3):

There is a great article and creating the smalest possible elf binary [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).  It has a lot of info of what is required to have something runnable by the os.

Comment: Another similar article can be found on the [ksplice blog](http://blog.ksplice.com/2010/03/libc-free-world/)

Answer (score 3):

This is logical trick.  Those who are unaware of it, can learn this trick.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) m##s##u##t
#define begin decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)
void begin()
{
    clrscr();
    printf("\nHello !!! Kaushal Patel.");
    getch();
}
```

**Explanation :**
The
 pre-processor directive #define with arguments is used to give an impression 
that the program runs without main(). But in reality it runs with a 
hidden main().

The ‘##‘ 
operator is called the token pasting or token merging operator. That is 
how, I can merge two or more characters with it.

```
#define decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) m##s##u##t
```

The macro 
`decode(s,t,u,m,p,e,d)` is being expanded as “msut” (The ## operator 
merges m,s,u & t into msut). The logic is when I pass 
(s,t,u,m,p,e,d) as argument it merges the 4th,1st,3rd & the 2nd 
characters.

```
#define begin decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e)
```

Here the 
pre-processor replaces the macro “begin” with the expansion 
decode(a,n,i,m,a,t,e). According to the macro definition in the previous
 line the argument must be expanded so that the 4th, 1st, 3rd & the 
2nd characters must be merged. In the argument (a,n,i,m,a,t,e) 
4th,1st,3rd & the 2nd characters are ‘m’,’a’,’i’ & ‘n’.

So the third line “void begin” is replaced by “void main” by the pre-processor before the program is passed on for the compiler.

Source :
http://ctechnotips.blogspot.in/2012/04/writing-c-c-program-without-main.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:->

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void _exit(register int);

int _start(){

printf(“Hello World\n”);

_exit(0);

}
```