# Static member variable initialization

Tags: c++

As posted below. How would i initialize the `alphabet` using `alphabet's` own member function for my `static member` variable? I need to do the initialization from within the "Text.cpp" implementation file.

```
Text.h

class Text {
private:

    struct Font {
        enum Enum {
            Arial,
            Menlo,
            Times
        };
    };

    static Alphabet alphabet[3]; // library of letters

}; // class
```

I need something as seen below, just the correct way of accomplish the task. I also need to initialize the `alphabet` only once for the duration of my runtime, thus i have made `alphabet` static. Thank you. ^^

```
Text.cpp

Alphabet Text::alphabet[Text::Font::Arial].Load("./Alphabet/", "Arial", ".xml"));
Alphabet Text::alphabet[Text::Font::Menlo].Load("./Alphabet/", "Menlo", ".xml"));
Alphabet Text::alphabet[Text::Font::Times].Load("./Alphabet/", "Times", ".xml"));
```

Comment: Please follow this link,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803953/static-constructor-in-c

Comment: @neo Thank you. It is good to know that static constructors can be emulated. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that Alphabet has a parametrized constructor, you can do it this way in a single translation unit (in Text.cpp file),

```
Alphabet Text::alphabet[] = { ("./Alphabet/", "Arial", ".xml"), 
                              ("./Alphabet/", "Menlo", ".xml"),
                              ("./Alphabet/", "Times", ".xml") };
```

Comment: Exactly - and to avoid duplication, the constructor can call `Load` internally. (there are some extra `)`s in your answer - might want to edit them out). +1

Comment: @Arun Thank you. I will overload my `alphabet` constructor to make this work. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: All the static variables declared in the class should be redefined in .cpp (implementation file, in your case Text.cpp), you shall initialize the variables in the definition.

Option 2: Add a new static method(function) in class "Text" to initialize the static members.
Since your static data member in private section. Declare the method in public section.