# How to initialize static members of a class?

Tags: c++, static, g++

I have written this code. It is giving no compile time errors but a runtime error. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this code?

It is giving this runtime error -> strap info: vpid 1: terminated with signal 11

```
    #include <iostream>

    class Color
    {
    public:
        static Color White, Black, Red, Green, Blue;

        unsigned char red, green, blue;

        static void static_Color();

        Color(unsigned char _red
        , unsigned char _green
        , unsigned char _blue)
        : red(_red), green(_green), blue(_blue)
        {
            static_Color();
        }
        
        Color()
        {
            static_Color();
        }
    };
    
    Color Color::White, Color::Black
    , Color::Red, Color::Green, Color::Blue;
    
    void Color::static_Color()
    {
        static bool called_before = false;

        if(called_before)
            return;

        Color::White = Color(255, 255, 255);
        Color::Black = Color(0, 0, 0);
        Color::Red = Color(255, 0, 0);
        Color::Green = Color(0, 255, 0);
        Color::Blue = Color(0, 0, 255);

        called_before = true;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        std::cout << (int) Color::Red.red;
    }
```

A needed feature [static constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297765/22493563).

Comment: Did you try (inside `Color`) to code: `static Color white={255,255,255};` and did you compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  then use the [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) debugger ?

Comment: Perfect use for a debugger.  You'll see that `static_color` is called recursively until stack overflow.

Comment: Right here `Color Color::White` is a call to the Color constructor, which calls `static_Color()`, which then calls the Color constructor 5 more times. Each of them then calls `static_Color()` again. Only ends when running out of memory for the calls.

Comment: Can't you make a `constexpr` here that can be used instead?

Comment: @tadman I made the members constexpr and inline. Now, it is saying Color is incomplete. Also a constexpr cannot be changed later. I have come up with this example. What if I don't want to make it constexpr??

Comment: Maybe functionality is broken in g++.

Comment: *"Maybe functionality is broken in g++"*  So there is either a bug in the compiler, or a bug in your code, Want to make a bet?  :-)  But seriously, the error sounds like you tried to put `Color` values inside the `Color` class. You cannot do that because the class is not fully known to the compiler until after the `};` at the end.

Comment: @BoP I removed static_Color(); call from constructors and added it to the main method. Now, it is working fine. The constructor and the static constructor were calling each other. Although there is a bool called_before but Compiler still got confused.

Comment: @PraveenO'Connell If you need to call a function in `main` to initialize your library, it seems like a bit of a failure. Can't you define the constant `Color` values _outside_ the `Color` class like I showed? You then have a header only library that doesn't require a call to any function.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo but then there will be multiple definitions of const values if the library has multiple header files.

Comment: @PraveenO'Connell No. An`inline`d variable will be linked ot the same variable. You can print the addresses of the pre-defined `Color`s in different translation units and you'll see that they are the same in all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `static_Color()` function. Just initialize them with the proper values where the `static` colors are defined:

```cpp
class Color {
public:
    static Color White, Black, Red, Green, Blue;

    unsigned char red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

    Color(unsigned char _red, unsigned char _green, unsigned char _blue)
        : red(_red), green(_green), blue(_blue) {}

    Color() = default;
};

// Here:
Color Color::White = Color(255, 255, 255);
Color Color::Black = Color(0, 0, 0);
Color Color::Red = Color(255, 0, 0);
Color Color::Green = Color(0, 255, 0);
Color Color::Blue = Color(0, 0, 255);
```

Right now, your the call to `static_Color()` in your constructor causes infinite recursion since every construction of a `Color` will cause a call to `static_Color()` that will again construct more `Color`s.

---

An alternative to having `static` member variables is to make some constants in your namespace. I've called the namespace `Color` too. You figure out a better one:

```cpp
namespace Color {
class Color {
public:
    unsigned char red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

    constexpr Color(unsigned char _red, unsigned char _green, unsigned char _blue)
        : red(_red), green(_green), blue(_blue) {}

    Color() = default;
};

inline constexpr Color White = Color(255, 255, 255);
inline constexpr Color Black = Color(0, 0, 0);
inline constexpr Color Red = Color(255, 0, 0);
inline constexpr Color Green = Color(0, 255, 0);
inline constexpr Color Blue = Color(0, 0, 255);
}  // namespace Color
```

Comment: What if I want to initialize these objects in header file? Maybe because it has header only and no cpp file.

Comment: @PraveenO'Connell  That's not what you have in your question though. I'm not sure that is possible since you can't make them `inline` since `Color` isn't complete yet. I added an alternative.