# Assigning value of global pointers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 9;
int *p;
p = &a;

int fun();

int main()
{
    std::cout << fun();
    return 0;
}

int fun()
{
    return *p;
}
```

Why does this code give the error:

> expected constructor, destructor, or
>   type conversion before '=' token|

Whereas this code runs OK:

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 9;
int *p = &a;

int fun();

int main()
{
    std::cout << fun();
    return 0;
}

int fun()
{
    return *p;
}
```

Comment: Please take care to [format your code as described in the FAQs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)

Answer (score 12):

You are allowed to declare and initialize variables/types globally not assign them.
`main()` is the start of the C++ program and assign statements would have to be inside main.

C++03 Standard: **section $3.6.1/1**:

> A program shall contain a global function called **main**, which is the designated start of the program.

If you coming from a Scripting background, you should note that C++ is different from Scripting languages in the way that you can declare items outside the bounds of designated start of program (`main()`), but you cannot do any processing(assignment or other statements).

Answer (score 5):

The assignment statement

```
p=&a;
```

is illegal in the place you've put it. Assignments must take place inside the body of a function.

The line

```
int *p=&a;
```

is legal because you're declaring and initialising a variable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881067/whats-wrong-with-this-c-program) is about a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

One of the confusing things about the language: Two basic constructs that use the same operator, =, meaning different things.

In the first case the = is just part of the syntax for initialisation, it isn't really operator= at all in that it isn't an assignment, although the consequence (post-condition) is the same: the variable ends up with that value. It is just different how it gets there.