# User-declared default constructor + in-class initializers != user-provided constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor, c++14, in-class-initialization

The [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#default_init_const) neatly explains that

> If a class or struct has no user-defined default constructor, C++
>   doesn't allow you to default construct a const instance of it like
>   this ([dcl.init], p9)

The rationale being that if a const object is not correctly initialized, it cannot be changed later on. The following code has only a user-**declared** default constructor for `Test`, but all its members have in-class initializers,

```
#include<iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    void print() const { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
private:
    int i = 42;   // will propagate to the default constructor!
};

int main()
{
    Test const t; // <-- Clang chokes on the const keyword, g++ does not
    t.print();    // prints 42
}
```

so the rationale for also user-**providing** the default constructor seems superfluous to me. And indeed, g++ 4.8.1 does compile it without problems ([Online Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=caea2c6da1f153c251ef555ff7dccdb4-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc)), although **Clang <= 3.2** does not.

**Questions**: why is the combination of complete in-class initalizers + user-declared default constructor not enough to default construct a const object? Is there a fix underway for the C++14 Standard?

**UPDATE**: can anyone try on Clang 3.3 / 3.4 to see if this has been fixed compared to Clang 3.2?

Comment: I think this is a mistake/bug in Clang, and g++ is correct to accept the code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Any Standard quote to go along with that? I ask because without the in-class initializer, the Standard says Clang is right.

Comment: Not really a quote, but by N3337, the wording had already been changed so this requirement had disappeared. Given that it *is* in the standard, I guess calling it a mistake or bug is probably slightly inaccurate, but at this point I think most compilers are mostly ignoring C++11 *per se* and pursuing newer drafts.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so is that DR that is marked as "active" already incorporated into the spec, contrary to what my answer states? With what solution?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: TBH, I'm not entirely sure -- the wording quoted in the DR seems to be gone, but that may be a side-effect of other editing, and they're still working on more changes to deal more specifically with this DR (or not -- without going back through meeting minutes I'm not sure why things changed to what they are now).

Comment: @abyss.7 erm, how could I look into the future? ;-)

Comment: @TemplateRex I've just read the questions about such situation on Meta - and the answers recommend to close the older question if it's not so informative. No offense at all.

Comment: @abyss.7 no offense was taken, I was just amused ;-)

Comment: As stated in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368753/852254 , this is resolved in clang in 3.9.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is a known problem. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#253 . It hasn't been fixed yet in the spec.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Nice to know it is on the radar.

Comment: Do you by any chance have access to Clang 3.3 / 3.4 to check if it is still an issue?

Comment: @TemplateRex Unfortunately, with clang 3.4 (trunk 184647) it is still an issue. :(

Comment: The issue resolution was finally applied in 2016.

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks, I changed the link.