# const T{}; works, const T; fails when T is a non-POD,

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, c++14

To start with, I have a struct with one value with a default value

```
struct S {
    int a = 1;
};
```

This type can be default constructed when it is non-const / non-constexpr by both gcc and clang.  Under both, `std::is_pod<S>::value` is `false`.  The weird behavior is as follows:

```
S s1; // works under both
const S s2{}; // works under both
const S s3; // only works in gcc, clang wants a user-provided constructor
```

None of the following attempts makes a difference to clang:

```
struct S {
    int a = 1;
    constexpr S() = default; // defaulted ctor
    virtual void f() { } // virtual function, not an aggregate
  private:
    int b = 2; // private member, really not an aggregate
};
```

The only thing I can do that makes this work is to add `constexpr S() { }` explicitly.  It seems really wrong to me that `const S s;` fails while `const S s{};` especially when the type is not an aggregate.

The standard makes me think that Clang is right
[N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf): 8.5/7

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a
>   const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided
>   default constructor

So why does gcc allow this, and is `S{};` not default initializing, even when the type is not a POD or an aggregate?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253; also `{}` is value-initialization for non-aggregates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does C++ require a user-provided default constructor to default-construct a const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a)

Comment: @David I think there's a little more here with the `= default`

Comment: I just added an answer to the question I marked this a duplicate of. The issue here is that the original wording required the constructor to be "user-provided". The updated wording provides exceptions to the "user-provided" requirement, which would allow your use case to compile. The reason `= default` did not work is because the standard defines user-provided as "A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
const S s3;
```

Is covered by [dcl.init]/12:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized.

Thus, as required by your quote, a user-provided default constructor must be present. Adding one like so

```
struct S {
    int a = 1;
    constexpr S(){}
};
```

then [makes the declaration compile fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/540d422344e281f4).

> [..] especially when the type is not an aggregate.

`S` **is an aggregate** in your case, and the reason why `const S s{}` is valid. Aggregate initialization is applied for `const S s{}`, and everything's fine.
If `S` is not an aggregate,

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - If `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1).
> - **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.**

Now consider the definition of value initialization:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a
>     (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default
>     constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - **if `T` is a (possibly
>     cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default
>     constructor, then
>          the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked**, and if
>         `T` has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

The default ctor is indeed nontrivial since a member has got an initializer ([class.ctor]/4.9), but that's irrelevant since the constraints are checked eitherway. Hence default-initialization it is, and the line

```
const S s{};
```

Is just as valid (or invalid!) as

```
const S t;
```

> So why does gcc allow this

Well:

1. Speaking in terms of the current standard, GCC is not compliant; See above.
2. There is an active CWG issue, [**#253**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253), created fifteen years ago, that covers a similar scenario. The final note on this one from a 2011 meeting says

   > If the implicit default constructor initializes all subobjects, no initializer should be required.

   That is the case with the implicit default constructor for `S`, and this would make all your lines valid.
3. GCC developers (e.g. [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57820#c5)) implied that since the committee basically agreed upon that above resolution, **the current behavior of GCC is feasible and should not be adjusted**. So one could well argue that GCC is right and the standard is broken.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57820 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60284. GCC is implementing the intended resolution to CWG 253.

Comment: @T.C. Intentionally? But even then, it's not standard compliant... shouldn't they "fix" the bug until this issue is closed?

Comment: What's the point of investing time changing the compiler to break user code when you know that the standard will be changed to allow such code?

Comment: See also Jonathan Wakely's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900237/do-i-really-need-to-implement-user-provided-constructor-for-const-objects#comment33170873_21900356).

Comment: I think I might agree with gcc, except maybe it needs a `--pedantic-including-broken-parts-of-standard-in-question` mode.

Comment: @Yakk `-reasonably-pedantic`?

Comment: @Columbo `--unreasonably-pedantic` -- the idea would be in C++11 mode, it would reject post-c++11 "bug fixes": try to reproduce the actual c++11 standard as best it could, warts and all.  As opposed to `--pedantic`, where including bug fixes to the standard (as opposed to extensions) are warnings.  The boundary between an extension and a preemptive bug fix for a non-resolved issue is admittedly fuzzy.

Answer (score 5):

So it looks like gcc is basing this on [DR 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) even though this is not resolved yet. We can see this from the the following [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60284) which says:

> This is by design, because as DR 253 shows, the normative standard is flawed.

and the [gcc change that brought this into effect](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=179170) says:

> Core 234 - allow const objects with no initializer or
>       user-provided default constructor if the defaulted constructor
>       initializes all the subobjects.

So technically `clang` is correct and `gcc` is not conformant but it seems like they believe `DR 253` will be resolved in their favor. This makes complete sense if the main concern is *indeterminate initial value* which as far as I can tell it is. This change is documented in [gcc 4.6 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html):

> In 4.6.0 and 4.6.1 G++ no longer allows objects of const-qualified
>   type to be default initialized unless the type has a user-declared
>   default constructor. In 4.6.2 G++ implements the proposed resolution
>   of DR 253, so default initialization is allowed if it initializes all
>   subobjects. Code that fails to compile can be fixed by providing an
>   initializer e.g.
>
> ```
> struct A { A(); };
> struct B : A { int i; };
> const B b = B();
> ```