# Why passing constexpr object by const reference works, but by value doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I have the code below, that basically maps an `std::integer_sequence<>` into an `std::array<>` at compile time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template<int...Is>
constexpr auto make_array(const std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>& param) // this works */
// constexpr auto make_array(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> param) // doesn't compile
{
    return std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)> {Is...};
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 1,2,3,4> iseq;

    // If I pass by value, error: the value of 'iseq' is not usable in a constant expression
    constexpr auto arr = make_array(iseq);  

    for(auto elem: arr)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

The code works fine whenever `make_array` takes its argument by `const`-reference. Whenever I try passing it by value, like in the commented line, it spits an error:

> error: the value of 'iseq' is not usable in a constant expression
>
> ```
>     constexpr auto arr = make_array(iseq);
> ```

Why is this? The parameter `iseq` is certainly a constant expression, why cannot I pass it to `make_array`?

For example, the code below works as expected when passing by value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
    int _m;
    constexpr Foo(int m): _m(m){};
};

constexpr Foo factory_foo(int m)
{
    return Foo{m};
}

constexpr Foo copy_foo(Foo foo)
{
    return foo;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr Foo cxfoo = factory_foo(42);
    constexpr Foo cpfoo = copy_foo(cxfoo);
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm using g++5.1 from macports. Using clang++ 3.5, I get an error message even for the code that compiles with g++ (with `const` reference):

> error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const
>         std::integer_sequence' requires a user-provided default
>         constructor

so I guess there is some issue with the lack of a user-provided default constructor, but at this point I don't really understand what's going on.

Comment: Which compiler(s) and version(s).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour g++5.1, will try on clang soon. See the updated edit, clang++ is spitting an error even in the case of passing by `const` reference. I am probably missing something about default-ctors in constant expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing an initializer on `iseq`. You have to add it:

```
constexpr std::integer_sequence<int, 1,2,3,4> iseq{};
                                                  ^^
```

From [dcl.constexpr]:

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and **shall be initialized**. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant expression (5.20). Otherwise, or if a `constexpr` specifier is used in a reference declaration, every fullexpression
>   that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression. *[ Note:* Each implicit conversion
>   used in converting the initializer expressions and each constructor call used for the initialization is part of
>   such a full-expression. *—end note ]*
>   *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct pixel {
>     int x, y;
> };
> constexpr pixel ur = { 1294, 1024 };  // OK
> constexpr pixel origin;               // error: initializer missing
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

Moreover, as Columbo suggests in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172483/why-passing-constexpr-object-by-const-reference-works-but-by-value-doesnt-comp/30172740#comment48452097_30172740) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172733/2069064), simply being initialized is insufficent. A user-provided constructor is also required, as per [dcl.init]:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type
>   with a **user-provided** default constructor.

It's a little odd to have the most relevant section (dcl.constexpr) have an incomplete description of the requirements for a `constepxr` object declaration.

Comment: Darn!!!! That was an easy fix :) Then I guess g++ has a bug. It didn't even cross my mind to check only the definition of `iseq`, for which clang++ would've spit an error.

Comment: Saw that quote when I checked about the implicit const thing, +1

Comment: @Columbo will report the bug for g++ (if it's not already reported)

Comment: @vsoftco Check with HEAD on Wandbox first.

Comment: @Barry IMO Your quote is not sufficient. Consider http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18119a57aa765be3 where arguably `a` is initialized, internally, but no user-provided constructor is present, which makes it ill-formed. :)

Comment: @Columbo compiles with HEAD gcc6

Comment: @Columbo That's a good point. I'd call it a wording defect. "Shall be initialized" is incomplete for the intent...

Comment: @Barry I wouldn't necessarily call this a defect, since the second quote you provided completes it (initializing and providing a user-provided ctor are orthogonal things). Maybe referring to [dcl.init] in a note would be appropriate.

Comment: @Columbo Less defect, more "sub-optimal word choice"?

Comment: Filled the bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66109, provided the wrong link before :)

Comment: gcc is probably allowing this [due to dr 253](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29683948/1708801)

Answer (score 6):

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a
>   const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided
>   default constructor.

However, `integer_sequence` does not have any user-provided constructors, and `constexpr` implies `const` for variables, so you can't define a `constexpr` object of that type without an initializer.
Adding an initializer [makes it compile on Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdb1f333f4e34280).