# default initialization of const qualified type with no user provided constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor, initialization, constants

Before you start to mark this as an duplicate I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900237/do-i-really-need-to-implement-user-provided-constructor-for-const-objects/21900356#21900356) but my question is about MSVS compiler. The linked question talks about g++ compiler.

I tried this program on MSVS 2015 compiler that is last updated on 3 Nov, 2015 [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)

```
class Test
{ };
int main()
{ const Test t; }
```

according to [**default initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) the above program should fail in compilation. It says that:

> If T is a const-qualified type, it must be a class type with a
> user-provided default constructor.

So, diagnosis is required in case of above program. But MSVS isn't giving any proper diagnosis. MSVS seems non-confirming here according to C++ standard. Is this bug in MSVS also like as in g++?

Comment: I think I recall reading that some people consider this a defect in the standard, that the code should be valid even if the standard currently says it's not. If I can find a reference I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @hvd: waiting for your valuable answer.

Comment: It was the same DR 253 that @101010 has found already by now. I'll not post a duplicate answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the draft standard *8.5/p7.3 Initializers [dcl.init]*:

> (7.3) — Otherwise, no initialization is performed
>
> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a
> const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided
> default constructor.

So you're right, a `const`-qualified object must have a user-provided constructor to be initialized.

This is due to fact that `const`-qualified objects are initialized once and if no default constructor is provided then the object would contain uninitialized values.

However, in your example `class Test` has no member variables. Strictly speaking, according to the standard is ill formed, but there's no harm since `Test` has no member variables.

For this reason the comittee filed a Defect Report [DR 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253). That says:

> If the implicit default constructor initializes all subobjects, no
> initializer should be required.

GCC follows that DR that's why it compiles the code, my guess is that for the same reason VC++ compiles the code as well.

However if you try to compile the following code:

```
class Test{ 
  int i;
};

int main() { 
  const Test t;
}
```

GCC will issue an error. VC++ 2015 will emit a diagnostic:

> warning C4269: 't': 'const' automatic data initialized with compiler
> generated default constructor produces unreliable results

Comment: It would be better If you file a bug. I don't  know about where to file this MSVS bug?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I revised my answer is not a bug there's a DR.