# Is an empty class usable as a constexpr variable without an initializer or explicit default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

Given the following code:

```
struct f {
};

int main(){
    constexpr f f1 ;
    //const f f1  ; // This also has the same issue
    //constexpr f f1 = {} ; //This works
}
```

clang and gcc disagree over whether it is valid, with clang providing the following diagnostic (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/phRBq2DeenTbBpYJ)*):

```
error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const f' without a user-provided default constructor
constexpr f f1 ;
            ^
              {}
```

As far as I can tell `f` is a literal type and it is initialized by the implicitly defaulted constructor which should allow it to be declared constexpr. Who is correct here?

Note, clang does accept the  declaration of `f1` if I explicitly add a constexpr default constructor:

```
constexpr f() {} ;
```

Does the answer change is `f` is not an aggregate?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809441/default-initialization-of-const-qualified-type-with-no-user-provided-constructor

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that is indeed related, thank you, I had to alter my answer because I was previously looking for *user-declared default constructor* whereas the terminology has changed to *user-provided default constructor*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we start from the draft C++14 standard section `7.1.5` *[dcl.constexpr]* we can find the requirements for a constexpr object declaration are:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant expression (5.19).

So is `f` is a literal type?

Section `3.9` *[basic.types]* says:

> A type is a literal type if it is:

and covers classes in the following bullet:

> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template
>       that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

So we are okay on the first and third bullet. To cover the second bullet, we could note that `f` is an *aggregate* but if we modify the example slightly, for example if `f` looked like this:

```
struct f {
   private:
      int x = 0 ;
} ;
```

which would not be an aggregate in either C++11 or C++14 but the issue would still exist. Then we need to show it has a constexpr constructor. Does `f` have a constexpr constructor?

As far as I can tell section `12.1` *[class.ctor]* says yes:

> [...] If that user-written default constructor would satisfy the requirements of a constexpr constructor (7.1.5),
>   the implicitly-defined default constructor is constexpr. [...]

But we are unfortunately required to have a user-provided constructor by section `8.5` which says:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type
>   with a user-provided default constructor.

So it looks like clang is correct here and if we look at the following clang bug report: ["error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const Z' requires a user-provided default constructor" even when no constructor needed](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23381). So clang is basing their lack of support for this due to [defect report 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) which does not currently have a proposed wording and it says (*emphasis mine*):

> Paragraph 9 of 8.5 [dcl.init] says:
>
> > If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of
> >     (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the
> >     object shall be default-initialized; **if the object is of
> >     const-qualified type, the underlying class type shall have a
> >     user-declared default constructor**. Otherwise, **if no initializer is
> >     specified for an object**, the object and its subobjects, if any, have
> >     an indeterminate initial value; if the object or any of its subobjects
> >     are of const-qualified type, **the program is ill-formed**.
>
> What if a const POD object has no non-static data members? This wording requires an empty initializer for such cases
>
> [...]
>
> Similar comments apply to a non-POD const object, all of whose non-static data members and base class subobjects have default constructors. Why should the class of such an object be required to have a user-declared default constructor?

The defect report is still open but the last comment on it says:

> If the implicit default constructor initializes all subobjects, no initializer should be required.

and also notes:

> This issue should be brought up again in light of constexpr constructors and non-static data member initializers.

Note the constraints on const qualified types moved around in section `8.5` since the defect report came about. This was due to proposal [N2762: Not so Trivial Issues with Trivial](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2762.htm) which was pre C++11.

Although the defect report is still open, given the constexpr changes and non-static data member initializers it does not seem like a necessary restriction anymore. Especially considering the following requirement on a constexpr constructor:

> - every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized (12.6.2);

Comment: The second bullet point says "it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) **or** ...". `f` is certainly an aggregate so we do not need to go into all that other stuff about constexpr constructors.

Comment: @M.M thank you, that is a good point. I actually started with a non-aggregate when I discovered this trying to prove some other issue I had. Then I wanted to simplify the problem but clearly I overlooked the fact that I had made `f` an aggregate in the process. I clarified and it does not really change the conclusion.

Comment: I still did not solve my original problem yet but this behavior is very unintuitive. It was like the first time I realized that non-static data member initializes made a class a non-aggregate in C++11.