# GCC accepts `constexpr struct {} s;` but Clang rejects it. Who is correct?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following code compiles fine with GCC:

```
constexpr struct {} s;
```

But Clang rejects it with the following error:

> error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const struct (anonymous struct at …)' without a user-provided default constructor

I've tested all versions of GCC and Clang that I was able to find at https://gcc.godbolt.org/. Each version of GCC accepts the code and each version of Clang rejects it.

**I wonder which compiler is correct in this case?

What does the standard say about this?**

Comment: [CWG253](http://wg21.link/CWG253).

Comment: @T.C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683381/const-t-works-const-t-fails-when-t-is-a-non-pod#comment47503814_29683381

Comment: @T.C. Can't believe what a f!cking ordeal it is to find the source of changes in the standard. I just spent 15 minutes using a bisection method to go through the git repo and Pete Becker's working drafts (fortunately including changes markup!), then going through each paper and core issue listed in the corresponding editor's report until I finally found what happened to [dcl.init]p7. One day I'll write something up to automatize that…

Comment: Also related to [Is an empty class usable as a constexpr variable without an intializer or explicit default constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33813929/1708801)

Comment: @Columbo I would happily pay for a tool like that, LOL.

Comment: Wanted to merely vote to reopen, but apparently single-handedly un-dupe-hammer my own questions. :/

Comment: I'd rather keep this open. The dupe mentions the same standard quote as the answer, but the question itself is different, and here we have a much more concise answer for this specific case.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Clang adheres to the following passage in [[dcl.init]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7):

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

This wording is [defective](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/253.html) and [hence ignored by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57820#c5) (and, as of v3.9, also by [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ed7vbGe0UTO1c9sz)). 
<sub>The above quote differs from core issue 253's due to [N2762](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2762.htm) moving/adjusting paragraph 9 as cited.</sub>

Comment: Wording ignored also by VC++2015