# A defaulted default constructor, why is it not a user-provided default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

For example, `clang` does not compile this code, because, the defaulted default constructor for `struct A` below, `A() = default;` is not considered to be user-provided.

```
struct A{ A() = default; };
const A a;
```

But if you look at [[dcl.fct.def.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#1) you'll see:

function-body:
     *ctor-initializer*<sub>*opt*</sub> *compound-statement*
     *function-try-block*
    `= default ;`
    `= delete ;`

That is, `= default;` is the **function body** for the default constructor `A::A()`, which is the same as saying that the definition `A() = default;` above is equivalent to `A(){}` as `{}`is the body for a default constructor.

By the way, `g++` compiles the snippet above, but I know `g++` has other issues in this regard, according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900237/do-i-really-need-to-implement-user-provided-constructor-for-const-objects#comment33170873_21900356) by Jonathan Wakely.

Comment: Strange, as you state, [clang fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45816775ce659464), [gcc compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/137a9ea1c836152b). So does VS2015.

Comment: User-provided explicitly-defaulted would look like `struct A{A();}; A::A()=default;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the standard says so ([[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#default-5)):

> A function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not
>   explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.

Doing it this way allows you to maintain the triviality property with `= default;`. Otherwise, there's no way to give a class with another constructor a trivial default constructor.

Comment: I think the term "deleted" on the quote you provided is not necessary, as [[dcl.fct.def.delete]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.delete#4) already prohibits a deleted definition from occurring after the function's first declaration. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Alexander that makes `A() = delete;` not user-provided.

Comment: But at least for the defaulted case we know that the function is either user-provided or implicitly provided by the compiler. But for a function that's explicitly deleted, I'm confused, because, as far as I know, this function is never defined. What would be the purpose of defining such a function, that will never be invoked?

Comment: @Alexander I don't get your question. `= delete;` is a definition. Classifying `A() = delete;` as not-user-provided doesn't mean you can define it yourself.