# clang won't default construct const class member

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I was thinking this is a clang bug, but just want to check I have my understanding correct of what should be happening.

I have a default-constructible class (the content of the class isn't relevant, I think, just that it's default-constructible)

```
struct MyClass1
{
    int i{};
};
```

and another class that contains a const member of that class type

```
struct MyClass2
{
    const MyClass1 m;
};
```

then at some point, I create a variable of type `MyClass2` like this

```
MyClass2 a;
```

My understanding is that this should default-construct an instance of `MyClass2`, which in turn should default-construct its `const` member instance of `MyClass1`, but compiling with clang (tested versions 4.0 through to 8) gives me the compile error

> error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'MyClass2'
>
> note: default constructor of 'MyClass2' is implicitly deleted because field 'm' of const-qualified type 'const MyClass1' would not be initialized

gcc compiles this as expected (versions 5 through 9), and clang compiles if I add an initialiser in for the class member like `const MyClass1 m{}` or the variable in main `MyClass2 a{}`.

What made me start to think that my understanding is incorrect is that gcc gives a similar error when I remove the initialiser from `MyClass1::i` (I'd have expected it to compile and just have `i` be initialised), as well as when I make `MyClass1` an empty struct (which I thought should be fine).

Comment: This quote from cppreference explains gcc's behaviour from my last paragraph:

"The implicitly-declared or defaulted default constructor for class T is undefined (until C++11)defined as deleted (since C++11) if any of the following is true:

- T has a const member without user-defined default constructor or a default member initializer (since C++11)."

Comment: There is a notion that const objects must be initialized, and in some language versions the interpretation has been that `m` itself requires an initializer even if it wouldn’t change anything.  That variation may be the source of this implementation divergence.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57318531/1505939) specifically; your code is correct since C++17