# Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor for type with const member

Tags: c++, clang, default-constructor

I see different behavior between gcc and clang compilers for this code:

```
#include <vector>

struct A { const std::vector<int> v; };

int main() { A a; }
```

clang can't compile it (https://godbolt.org/z/v-nEir):

```
<source>:5:16: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'A'
int main() { A a; }
               ^
<source>:3:35: note: default constructor of 'A' is implicitly deleted because field 'v' of const-qualified type 'const std::vector<int>' would not be initialized

struct A { const std::vector<int> v; };
```

gcc compiles it without errors: https://godbolt.org/z/Sy96DU

I found a similar question:
[Why does C++ require a user-provided default constructor to default-construct a const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a) and from the answers it seems like `A` should be const-default-constructible and clang has a bug. Who is correct here?

Comment: I'm not at all sure here - but could this be a difference between `C++11` and later standards?

Comment: This seems essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/57318531/1505939 . The code was incorrect in C++11 (which required const objects to have an explicit initializer) and correct as of C++17 which allows const objects with no initializer if they have a default constructor. clang seems slow to implement this change