# Unused const object of class with virtual desctructor causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, segmentation-fault, mingw

I was struggling with segmentation fault after returning from main in C++0x code compiled under GCC with MinGW, and have narrowed it to simple case:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A();
};

A::~A() {
}

const A a;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The reason is correlated with:

1. `const` qualifier before object, removing it stops seg fault,
2. Lack of constructor in `class A` - adding empty one stops seg fault.
3. Version of compialtor - newer TDM MinGW with gcc 4.8.1 does not build code causing seg fault.

**Am I triggering some undefined behavior, or really compiler bug is reason of such behavior?**

Affected compiler:

> gcc --version
> gcc.exe (tdm-1) 4.7.1
>
> g++ --version
> g++.exe (tdm-1) 4.7.1
>
> ld --version
> GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.22

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a

Comment: @yngum: Was that restriction scrapped post-11? Or where is it in the newest draft?

Comment: @Deduplicator No, 8.5.6 on the newest draft.

Comment: @yngum: You mean 8.5§6? Because there's no 8.5.6... Still, 8.5§6 in n3797 does not seem to handle that either...

Comment: @Deduplicator In that case it is 8.5§7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be [gcc bug 55893](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55893) that was fixed in 4.7.3. The attached testcase is very similar to yours:

```
struct foo
{
  virtual ~foo () { }
};

int main ()
{
  static const foo tmp;
}
```

The error occurs because gcc places the `const` object in read-only memory, because it is trivially constructible, without checking that the object has a non-trivial destructor. The destructor, being `virtual`, attempts to update the vtable pointer, leading to the segfault.

Comment: Which naturally raises the question of why the destructor call is not simply optimized out ...