# discrepancy between clang and g++ in dealing with const objects

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

Consider the code:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x = 10;
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo;
}
```

It compiles under g++ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99bd8006e10b47ef, however spits an error under clang++ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93f94f7d9625b579 :

```
error: default initialization of an object of const type
      'const Foo' requires a user-provided default constructor
```

I am not sure who's right here. Why do we need a default ctor since we perform in-class initialization?

Comment: Here is a great answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a

Comment: This is [CWG issue 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253).

Comment: @Furkan, note that I know why the rule is as it is, I don't understand why is it applicable in my case, as my object is perfectly well defined at runtime.

Comment: @T.C.: Are you sure a core issue from 2000 is relevant?

Comment: @KerrekSB: consider the comment from the august 2011 meeting, "If the implicit default constructor initializes all subobjects, no initializer should be required.". that's clearly the *intent* for c++11. it didn't make it into the standard, though.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't know what exactly "implicit default constructor initializes all subobjects" means here. If I do in-class initialization, is it internally transformed into an implicit default ctor that performs it?

Comment: @vsoftco: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An object of class type may only be default-initialized if it has a user-provided default constructor. From [dcl.init]/7:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

Your class `Foo` doesn't have that; the presence of a *brace-or-equals-initializer* does not create a user-provided default constructor. Rather, your class has an *implicitly defined* default constructor, whose action incorporates the initialization as requested by the *brace-or-equals-initializer*. (Clang is right.)

([dcl.fct.def.default], in particular paragraph 5, relates the definitions of "user-provided", "explicitly defaulted", "implicitly declared" and "defined as deleted". The entire section is worth knowing.)

By the way, it's easy to avoid default-initialization in C++11:

```
const Foo foo {};  // hunky-dory
```

Comment: What difference does `{}` make??

Comment: @0x499602D2 it value-initializes, so the compiler is happy that in a `const` you have everything initialized. I guess the problem in my case is when you have an additional `y` variable that you don't in-class initialize. Standard C++ decided that it won't bother checking that all members are in-class initialized, so the old rule is still applicable.

Comment: @vsoftco: In C++14, I think it would be aggregate-initialization. The rules have changed a little bit to allow aggregates to have BOEIs.

Comment: @KerrekSB what is BOEIs? Sorry for my ignorance :)

Comment: @vsoftco: *brace-or-equals-initializer*. I got tired of typing that :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB ha ha, ok, will remember. And just tested that g++ (4.9.2) doesn't yet allow BOEI for aggregates with `-std=c++14`, but clang++ does.

Answer (score 3):

[clang](http://clang.llvm.org) seems to be right according to 8.5 [dcl.init] paragraph 7 last sentence:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a `const`-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a user-provided default constructor.

Clearly, the type doesn't have a user-provided default constructor.