# Default Initializer of empty struct in clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, clang++

The following code compiles with some versions with GCC and some versions of Clang (see below which versions).

```
struct my_struct {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const my_struct my_object;
  return 0;
};
```

Compile with :`g++ clang_error.cpp` and `clang++ clang_error.cpp`. Where I had g++ at *4.8.4* and clang++ at 3.6.0.

The error message is:

```
clang_error.cpp:7:19: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const my_struct' without a user-provided default constructor
   const my_struct my_object;
                   ^
clang_error.cpp:7:28: note: add an explicit initializer to initialize 'my_object'
   const my_struct my_object;
                            ^
                             = {}
1 error generated.
```

## Versions affected

Using the *Compiler Explorer* [here](https://godbolt.org/g/V770Wr), I can see that GCC up to 4.5.4 is affected. Clang is affected up to 3.9.0.

## Question

My question is: **What does the C++ standard say about this?** Ideally, I'd care about C++14 but I'm not picky there.

**Is the above example code standard-conformant?**

### What I found so far

I found the following in [Draft N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) of C++14.

> § 7.1.6.1 The cv-qualifiers [dcl.type.cv]
>   2 [ Note: Declaring a variable const can affect its linkage (7.1.1) and its usability in constant expressions (5.19).
>   As described in 8.5, the definition of an object or subobject of const-qualified type must specify an initializer
>   or **be subject to default-initialization.** — end note ]
>
> § 8.5
>   7 To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) for T is called (and
>   **the initialization is ill-formed if T has no default constructor** or overload resolution (13.3) results in an
>   ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   — otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Comment: Please suggest better tags.

Comment: looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a) explains it.

Comment: So newer versions of GCC and Clang are broken with regards to the standard? Surely, there must be a rule in the standard that allows the current behavior of these compilers. Your linked answer, while useful, did not answer this question to me.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28338265/461597) might be the answer. It links to [this](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) issue of the Standard Committee for C++11. Now, only a link to which resolution the Standard came is needed.

Comment: You are correct, it's Core issue 253. GCC documented its change of behaviour for gcc 4.6 at https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html#cplusplus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the C++ standard say about this?
>
> Is the above example code standard-conformant?

In C++14, it is non-conformant:

> n4431 (2015) standard draft [dcl.init] / 7:
>
> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a const-qualified type
> T
> ,
> T
> shall be a class type
> with a user-provided default constructor.

`my_struct` has no user-provided default constructor, so you shall not default-initialize.

However, some newer compilers appear to have chosen to relax the rule, possibly because it is subject to a defect report: [DR 253](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253).

---

The upcoming standard has changed wording:

> Current (2017) standard draft [[dcl.init] / 7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7):
>
> A class type T is const-default-constructible if default-initialization of T would invoke a user-provided constructor of T (not inherited from a base class) or if
>
> (7.4) each direct non-variant non-static data member M of T has a default member initializer or, if M is of class type X (or array thereof), X is const-default-constructible,
>
> (7.5) if T is a union with at least one non-static data member, exactly one variant member has a default member initializer,
>
> (7.6) if T is not a union, for each anonymous union member with at least one non-static data member (if any), exactly one non-static data member has a default member initializer, and
>
> (7.7) each potentially constructed base class of T is const-default-constructible.
>
> If a program calls for the default-initialization of an object of a const-qualified type T, T shall be a const-default-constructible class type or array thereof.

The wording is a bit ambiguous to me, but I think that since `my_struct` has no members that violate 7.4 (and is not a union, so 7.5 does not apply, has no union members so 7.6 does not apply and no bases, so 7.7 does not apply), it is const-default-constructible and therefore the example will be conformant.