# Does initialization of constexpr instance (e.g. `std::integral_constant`) require `={}`?

Tags: c++11

The following declaration fails in clang 3.8.1 but seems to compile without error in other compilers tested (e.g. gcc 6.1, MSVC 2015, clang 3.9.1).

```
constexpr std::integral_constant<int,0> myConstant;
```

clang 3.8.1 gives:

> `error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const std::integral_constant<int, 0>' without a user-provided default constructor
>   constexpr std::integral_constant<int,0> myConstant;`

Whereas the following compiles correctly in all compilers tested:

```
constexpr std::integral_constant<int,0> myConstant = {};
```

What is going on here? (is the clang 3.8.1 error correct?)

If I define my own type, should I write a user-provided default ctor so that users can avoid typing `={}` ?

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` variables *must* be initialized. A declaration of the form `Typename variablename;` will perform default initialization on `variablename`.

Types which do not have a trivial default constructor will, under default initialization, be *uninitialized*. Normally that's fine.

But `constexpr` variables are not permitted to be uninitialized. Therefore, for types with trivial default constructors, you have to visibly initialize them. By doing `= {}` to the variable, you are causing it to be value initialized, which will zero out the object.

This should not be considered a problem. In general, you should *always* visibly initialize a `constexpr` variable, even if it's just with `= {}`. That way, it's clear to everybody what you're doing.

And no, you should not add default constructors to types just so that people can make `constexpr` variables of them without visibly initializing them. You should only add a user-provided default constructor to a type if the type *needs* one to do its job.

---

As for the compiler behavior, that's on them. Clang's behavior in 3.8.1 is correct with regard to the specification, so the others are incorrect.

Comment: `std::integral_constant` has no value representation (it's an empty struct). Does your "you should always visibly initialize" rule still apply?

Comment: @RossBencina: "*std::integral_constant has no value representation*" The standard is quite clear that all `constexpr` variables "shall be initialized". Whether it has a value representation is not something the standard cares about. This is also true of any variable declared in a `constexpr` function.

Comment: This answer does not currently address my question "What is going on here?" -- why is the behavior different between different compilers? which compiler is correct?

Comment: @RossBencina: I thought the answer to "which compiler is correct" would be obvious, given my explanation of what the *standard* requires. But I've made the answer more explicit.

Comment: @RossBencina: Then it has a regression, since you stated that 3.8.1 worked (ie: gave an error). I have explained what the C++ standard says should happen. You can judge that against specific compiler versions and file bugs on them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338265/2013747, whether `={}` is needed is an open issue that clang and gcc originally chose to implement differently. Allowing `={}` to be omitted appears to be the direction that is preferred by the CWG, and clang 3.9 changed policy to reflect that.

Quoting CWG active issue #253:

> *253. Why must empty or fully-initialized const objects be initialized?*
>
> []
>
> Paragraph 9 of 8.6 [dcl.init] says:
>
> If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly >cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or array thereof), the object shall be >default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying >class type shall have a user-declared default constructor. Otherwise, if no >initializer is specified for an object, the object and its subobjects, if any, >have an indeterminate initial value; if the object or any of its subobjects are >of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed.
>
> What if a const POD object has no non-static data members? **This wording requires an empty initializer for such cases** [...]

(Emphasis added.) The conclusion here is that for compatibility with older compilers, and strict adherence to the standard, `={}` must be used unless there is a user-declared default ctor.

The old clang behavior resulted from the above conservative interpretation
of the language specification. CWG August 2011 meeting resolved:

> Notes from the August, 2011 meeting:
>
> **If the implicit default constructor initializes all subobjects, no initializer should be required.**

Source: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253

As far as I know, this change has not yet been incorporated into any version of the C++ standard. Therefore, while omitting `={}` will likely continue to compile, and may in future be officially supported by the standard, it is not currently part of the official ISO standard.