# When and how to default-initialize a const variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-constructor

`clang++` does not ever allow [default initialization of a const variable of class-type without a user-defined constructor](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#default_init_const); `g++` is slightly less restrictive (see below). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411708/1858225), this is because POD types "are not initialized by default." If I understand correctly, this means that default-initialization does not invoke the default-constructor, nor does it invoke value-initialization, so the data members inside the POD type are not initialized. Of course it makes no sense to have a const POD type with uninitialized values in it, since they can *never* be initialized and therefore are not safe to use.

There are a few variants of this situation:

1. The type is technically "POD", but contains no data members (only functions). (`clang++` does not treat this as a special case, nor, I think, does the standard, but `g++` does allow it, even when the constructor is marked `explicit`.)
2. An empty constructor is defined using `{}`. (This is the recommended workaround on the `clang` page describing the issue.)
3. The default constructor is declared `=default`. (C++11 onward; the type is still considered POD, so neither compiler nor the standard treat it as a special case.)
4. Aggregate initialization is explicitly invoked using `{}`, which (if I understand correctly) becomes value-initialization. (C++11 onward; both compilers—and, I think, the standard—allow this.)

In the first case, there can be no *uninitialized* members, so it's unclear why any instantiation of the class itself would ever be considered "uninitialized," regardless of whether or not it's `const`. Since `g++` allows this behavior, is it safe to use? Why is it prohibited by `clang++` and the standard? (And are there any other cases where `g++` allows POD-default-initialization where `clang++` does not?)

In the second and third cases, the requirement of using `{}` instead of `=default` seems odd to me. **EDIT:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20828970/1858225) explains the difference quite well, so I've removed the part of the question asking about the distinction. (I still think it's a terribly confusing aspect of the language, though.)

Finally, will `Foo f{}` always zero-initialize members of built-in type if `Foo::Foo(void)` is `{}`, `=default`, or implicitly-declared?

Comment: Is there a use-case for a const POD type with no member variables? You may as well use a non-const one, since there are no members that could be erroneously changed.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not sure. This is a pattern that recurs repeatedly in a colleague's code, in templated factory functions (or...something like that). I'll try to remember to ask said colleague tomorrow what the intent is.

Comment: A constructor defined with `{}` is not a trivial constructor.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Good lord this language has terrible terminology. What's the appropriate name? Is there one?

Comment: @KyleStrand I'd say "empty"

Comment: @MattMcNabb the idea is apparently that the signature of the function that returns a const reference (partly) indicates a level of thread safety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since g++ allows this behavior, is it safe to use?

Safe in what sense? It's obviously not portable currently. However, it's not going to give you unexpected results on g++.

> Why is it prohibited by clang++ and the standard?

Presumably the committee either didn't think about it when they put the "user-provided constructor required" rule in C++98, or decided that special-casing empty POD classes isn't worth the specification complexity; clang++ is just following the standard.  However, the standard is [likely going to change](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#253) to more generally allow you to write `const Foo f;` as long as the constructor will, in fact, initialize every subobject.

> Finally, will `Foo f{};` always zero-initialize members of built-in
>   type if `Foo::Foo(void)` is `{}`, `=default`, or implicitly-declared?

Yes for the latter two. No for the first. That one counts as user-provided, so value-initialization doesn't perform zero-initialization before calling the default constructor.

Comment: I did indeed mean "safe" in the "unexpected results" sense. Once again, nice open-standard link; how do you find those so quickly (or at all)? Also, when you say "value-initialization doesn't perform zero-initialization before calling the default constructor," do you mean that zero-initialization won't (necessarily) happen *at all*? So changing from `=default` to `{ }` can actually *introduce* improper-initialization bugs?

Comment: @KyleStrand 1) This particular g++/clang++ difference has been asked about on SO before, so I know that there's an open core issue on this :) 2) Yes, it's not guaranteed to happen, though the implementation can clobber the memory however it likes (as no well-defined program can observe it). Technically speaking, it's indeterminate, and reading it causes UB (modulo a few exceptions for `unsigned char`); 3) Yes.