# Error while compiling NDK libraries for FBReader

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I am trying to compile FBreader libraries to use with my project. Two of the .so libraries are being compiled successfully but on the last library it is giving me the following error

```
jni/NativeFormats/fbreader/src/formats/xhtml/XHTMLReader.cpp:42:31: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const XHTMLTagInfoList' without a
      user-provided default constructor
static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST;
                              ^
```

After looking at the c++ code following is the line where the error is occuring

```
static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST;
```

And the `XHTMLTagInfoList` var is

```
const XHTMLTagInfoList &XHTMLReader::tagInfos(size_t depth) const {
        if (myTagDataStack.size() < depth + 2) {
                return EMPTY_INFO_LIST;
        }
        return myTagDataStack[myTagDataStack.size() - depth - 2]->Children;
}
```

I am not that good at c++. Please help in resolving the error

After updating to `static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST{};`

Following error is occuring

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: so, have you found the solution? 
Or you just omitted const from `static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST;`?

Comment: Just omitted the `const` part and its working fine.

Comment: btw, i found another solution, if you add `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9`
in the Application.mk build goes with no errors

Comment: Will try that too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll quote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a):

The C++ standard (section 8.5) says:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a
>   const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided
>   default constructor.

if we'd go to XHTMLTagInfoList [definition](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ/blob/b0782b20d42d66adf846f61c351785ff95192e23/jni/NativeFormats/fbreader/src/formats/xhtml/XHTMLTagInfo.h) we would see that it does not have user defined ctor indeed.

To fix your problem you just need to use empty initializer:

```
static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST{};
```

Note, that it would not be required for non-const declaration

---

Edit: Note that you most likely don't have -std=c++11 enabled, that would fix your error

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in the morning and will let you know if it works. I hope it works.

Comment: I have added `{}` after `EMPTY_INFO_LIST`, but now am getting following error
`jni/NativeFormats/fbreader/src/formats/xhtml/XHTMLReader.cpp:42:31: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const XHTMLTagInfoList' without a
      user-provided default constructor
static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST{};
                              ^
jni/NativeFormats/fbreader/src/formats/xhtml/XHTMLReader.cpp:42:46: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST{};
                                             ^
` . Please help.

Comment: Sorry how am I supposed to know which line number is for what? The last error is about semicolon, have you added one?

Comment: I have added the screenshot in my question. Currently I have removed const and built it, will it have any adverse effects on the library. I will give it try after adding semicolon.

Comment: Have tried adding semicolon after `EMPTY_INFO_LIST` so the line is now `static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST;{};`. Which also is giving error as `error: expected unqualified-id
static const XHTMLTagInfoList EMPTY_INFO_LIST;{};`

Comment: No the last line does not make any sense, I thought you could have forgot to add in at the end of the whole line. As for making object non const, it should not make any adverse effect unless you will go and modify object in unexpected (for library) way, because now you cam modify it

Comment: So, what should be the way forward? Should I go with having a `non-const` var or is there any other way to overcome it? I have not made any changes the `struct` or it's `class`.

Comment: non-const version wont do any harm. Clang and gcc seem to have different opinions on this issue, Im almost sure you are building with gcc toolchain, change to clang would take this issue away but may bring up other incompatibilities, no point in doing this now

Comment: oh i know, you dont have c++11 enabled in your build, that would fix it

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I will now go and build FBreader. Now importing it to Android Studio is also a pain. I have tried importing but most of the Java files are not being copied to the new structure. Will resolve it  now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ok I will explore c++11 option also. And how do I enable it please.

Comment: you add `APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11` line in your Application.mk file. If you think this is enough please accept an answer (or dont if you think it missed the target)

Comment: After adding c++11 I am getting multiple errors like this one `jni/NativeFormats/fbreader/src/formats/doc/OleStorage.cpp:62:52: error: constant expression evaluates to 224 which cannot be narrowed to type 'char' [-Wc++11-narrowing]
        static const char OLE_SIGN[] = {0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0xE1, 0};
` Its asking for explicit casting to silent the error

Comment: Sorry, we can't just go fixing your code line by line, right? I suggest going with non-const solution

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help though. I will accept the answer as it may give pointers to people if they are stuck on the same. Going with non-const solution then.