# Object returned from lambda loses property value

Tags: c++, lambda

I am taking a course that is several years old so learning how to use serialization for the first time.

When the "return result" executes in the lambda, the Address property of the Contact becomes uninitialized.  The commented out code works just fine so I am fairly sure that I compiled the Boost libraries ok.

The name on the Contact comes back ok.  Why doesn't the Address?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

struct Address
{
public:
    string street, city;
    int suite;

    Address() {};
    Address(string street, string city, int suite)
        : suite(suite),street(street),city(city){ }

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Address& obj)
  {
    return os
      << "street: " << obj.street
      << " city: " << obj.city
      << " suite: " << obj.suite;
  }

private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template<class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & street;
    ar & city; 
    ar & suite;
  }
};

struct Contact
{
  string name;
  Address* address;


  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Contact& obj)
  {
    return os
      << "name: " << obj.name
      << " address: " << *obj.address;
  }
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template<class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & name;
    ar & address;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Contact john;
  john.name = "John Doe";
  john.address = new Address{ "123 East Dr", "London", 123 };

  auto clone = [](Contact c)
  {
    ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa << c;

    string s = oss.str();

    Contact result;
    istringstream iss(s);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);
    ia >> result;
    return result;
  };

  // This works fine
  //ostringstream oss;
  //boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
  //oa << john;

  //string s = oss.str();

  //Contact newJane;
  //{
     // istringstream iss(s);
     // boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);
     // ia >> newJane;
  //}

  //newJane.name = "Jane";
  //newJane.address->street = "123B West Dr";

  //cout << john << endl << newJane << endl;


  Contact jane = clone(john);
  jane.name = "Jane";
  jane.address->street = "123B West Dr";

  cout << john << endl << jane << endl;

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, implement the rule of 5. Right now, a Contact performs shallow copies of its Address pointer (I'm on mobile so that's about all I can do for you at the moment)

Comment: @AndyG You are correct, that is what is needed.  The instructor used the above code and it worked.  I was trying to duplicate what he did.  Post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Why are you using pointers to `Address`es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contact` does not overload the copy constructor. Hence, the default is generated.

The default copy constructor copies all (non-`static`) member variables using their default constructors. Specifically, the default constructor of a pointer just copies the address which is stored.

So, using the copy construction of `Contact`, there is constructed a new instance with `Contact::address` pointing to the exact same `Address` like the original instance.

Hence, changing the address of `jane` will change the address of `joe` as well.

This may be intended or not:

- intentional to share resources
- unintentional if `Contact` shall have exclusive ownership of its `address`.

If `jane` and `joe` are not married this might be unintended.

In its current state, the design has another flaw:

Which instance is responsible to delete the `address` pointee when a `Contact` is destroyed?

If it would be added to the destructor `~Contact()` things start to become worse.
(Deleteing `jane` would delete her address and leaving `john` with a dangling pointer.)

As it is now, destroying a `Contact` may produce a memory leak. (Outside code had to be responsible to delete left instances of `Address`. This is hard to maintain.)

Such design issues are not rare and leaded to the [**Rule of three**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) which says:

If one of

- destructor
- copy constructor
- copy assignment operator

is explicitly defined then the other most probably too.

With C++11 (introducing move semantics), this was extended to the **Rule of Five** adding

- move constructor
- move assignment operator.

Thereby, one explicit definition may be simply to delete them:

```
struct Contact {
  Address *address;

  // default constructor with initialization to empty
  Contact(): address(new Address()) { }

  // constructor with values
  Contact(const Address &address): address(new Address(address)) { }

  // destructor.
  ~Contact()
  {
    delete address; // prevent memory leak
  }

  // move constructor.
  Contact(Contact &&contact): address(contact.address)
  {
    contact.address = nullptr; // prevent two owners
  }
  // move assignment.
  Contact& operator=(Contact &&contact)
  {
    address = contact.address;
    contact.address = nullptr; // prevent two owners
    return *this;
  }

  // prohibited:
  Contact(const Contact&) = delete;
  Contact& operator=(const Contact&) = delete;
};
```

This is an improvement concerning memory management but counter-productive concerning the intention to `clone()` instances of `Contact`.

Another possible solution is to store `address` as `std::shared_ptr<Address>` instead of `Address*`. [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (one of the *smart pointers*) has been introduced for such kinds of problems (concerning shared ownership).

```
struct Contact {
  std::shared_ptr<Address> address;

  // default constructor with initialization to empty
  Contact(): address(std::make_shared<Address>()) { }

  // constructor with values
  Contact(const Address &address):
    address(std::make_shared<Address>(address))
  { }

  // another constructor with values
  Contact(const std::shared_ptr<Address> &address):
    address(address)
  { }

  // destructor.
  ~Contact() = default;
  /* default destructor of shared_ptr is fully sufficient
   * It deletes the pointee just if there are no other shared_ptr's to it.
   */

  // copy constructor.
  Contact(const Contact&) = default; // copies shared_ptr by default
  // copy assignment.
  Contact& operator=(const Contact&) = default; // copies shared_ptr by default
  // move constructor.
  Contact(Contact&&) = default;
  // move assignment.
  Contact& operator=(Contact&&) = default;
};
```

Setting the "Five" to default is in this case effectively the same like leaving them out.

---

Links I found while checking not to write anything stupid:

- [SO: Defaulted constructor vs implicit constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41219291/7478597)
- [SO: Is a `=default` move constructor equivalent to a member-wise move constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18290523/7478597)

Comment: I much prefer the Rule of Zero, and have the member be `Address address;`

Comment: @Caleth Of course. I agree. I assumed, that OP showed an MCVE and there might be (other) reasons to use a pointer for `Address` (e.g. the teacher required it). However, I see your answer as third option (to round up the topic).

Comment: This course was done over 2 years ago and the teacher showed it working as I posted it.  It didn't make sense to me why it worked hence my question here.  This segment was more about the boost serialization handling pointers rather than the design of the classes.

Comment: @ACThompson Sorry, after having read your comment to AndyG, I might have got a wrong impression. The excluded code doesn't change the weakness of the class design. It has worked as the weakness didn't effect the parts which were actually used.

Comment: @Scheff The class design was purposely weak in the class design as it was not the focus.  Showing how boost serialization handled Address address and Address* address without changes was the teacher's point.  When I used the teacher's code, the contact was not being returned from the lambda like it was for the teacher.  I implemented the what you and AndyG suggested, it worked just fine as you would expect.  Unsure why worked different in the course presentation and since I am relatively new to C++, I brought my question here. I now have confirmation I am not missing something with lambdas.

Comment: @ACThompson I just had a look at [Boost.Serialization - Pointers and References](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization-pointers-and-references) as I couldn't imagine how your teachers example should be a working example. I learned that _If the archive is restored, **a** will not necessarily contain the same address. A new object is created and its address is assigned to **a** instead._ There is nothing mentioned how the previous contents of **a** is managed. (Ignored? Deleted?) Your teacher provided a new constructed object while you took a copied. That's the difference.

Comment: @ACThompson Keeping in mind what I wrote about default constructors, it may explain why your teachers example worked but your's not. I agree, the lambda doesn't play an active role in this - a free-standing function, or just the code in this place had probably caused the same.

Comment: @ACThompson  Btw., the doc. in the above link mentions also that _Please note that Boost.Serialization hasn’t been updated for C++11, yet. Smart pointers from the C++11 standard library like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` are not currently supported by Boost.Serialization._ Strange, that I couldn't find the boost version the doc. relies on. (Normally, you have always the choice to switch to current version - or any other.) This makes it a bit mysterious...

Answer (score 1):

There's no compelling reason to use pointers to `Address` in `Contact`, so don't. This also means that the compiler generated copy constructor can replace `clone`.

```
struct Contact
{
  string name;
  Address address;

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Contact& obj)
  {
    return os
      << "name: " << obj.name
      << " address: " << obj.address;
  }
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template<class Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & name;
    ar & address;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Contact john;
  john.name = "John Doe";
  john.address = Address{ "123 East Dr", "London", 123 };

  Contact jane = john;
  jane.name = "Jane";
  jane.address.street = "123B West Dr";

  cout << john << endl << jane << endl;

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was part of a class that was teaching serialization and the address pointer was originally a struct and changed to a pointer to show that the boost serialization handled a pointer just fine.