# Are members of a class with defaulted constructors zero-initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, language-lawyer

If I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
   public:
    int value;
};
```

It's member `value` won't be zero-initialized if I don't zero-initialize the class:

```
MyClass c;
std::cout << c.value; // UB: value not initialized.
```

**Does defaulting the default constructor guarantee that members are zero-initialized?**

```
class MyClass {
   public:
    int value;
    MyClass() = default;
};
```

If I explicitly default the default constructor, will `value` be initialized to zero now?

```
MyClass c;
std::cout << c.value; // Guaranteed to print zero?
```

**Note:** This question is not a duplicate because I'm asking about the case where the default constructor is *explicitly* defaulted, and the other question just covers the case where it's not provided.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219291/defaulted-constructor-vs-implicit-constructor and a few more questions.

Comment: I'm asking about the specific case where it's explicitly defaulted, not the case where it's not provided at all.

Comment: The question you linked doesn't provide an answer regarding differences in the initialization of primitives that are member variables

Comment: AFAIK, on GCC it will generate you a warning `'c.MyClass::value' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]` and print 0, but Clang won't issue you a warning, and will print 0. I'm talking about the latest  Clang 9.0.1 and Gcc 9.0.1

Comment: The first comment answers the "how is explicitly defaulted different" part - it's identical with regard to member initialization. The difference is in access control.

Comment: Thank you - sorry about that

Comment: @mutantkeyboard: That's the problem with Undefined Behavior - it may give results that **look** reliable. Visual Studio in debug builds probably will not give 0, as it intentionally writes non-zero patterns prior to initialization.