# Declaring a const object in C ++ requires a user-defined default constructor. If I have a mutable member variable, why not?

Tags: c++, clang++

In C++, to declare an object of a class that has a member variable as `const`, we must have a user-defined default constructor. The following code illustrates this.

```
class Some {
    int value;
};

int main() {
    // error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const Some'
    //        without a user-provided default constructor
    const Some some;

    return 0;
}
```

However, if a member variable owned by a class is qualified as mutable, the compiler will not report any errors. For reference, I compiled using the command `clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.out --debug`. I wonder if this result is due to a bug in the compiler or according to the syntax defined in the C++ language.

```
class Some {
    mutable int value;
};

int main() {
    const Some some;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that [GCC gives an error about it, and MSVC gives a warning that isn't directly related to it](https://godbolt.org/z/P_6eeU).

Comment: does this answer your question? [Why does C++ require a user-provided default constructor to default-construct a const object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a)

Comment: `mutable` is kind of the opposite of `const`. Why did you expect the same effect?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Member variables that are qualified with mutable are no different from variables with no qualifiers, except that they can also be changed in the const function. The link you posted doesn't seem to mention mutable-specific member variables, can you confirm it?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Even forcing [C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/CAaTm7), gcc produces an error, MSVC a warning, but clang only complains about the unused variables. [Using](https://godbolt.org/z/YRY8uC) somehow that variable, gcc still produces an error, MSVC still warns about the suspicious initialization and clang happily has UB.

Comment: @Bob__ I guess it's a bug because C++17 is very clear about this issue in its documentation.

Comment: Cause it makes no sense initializing an object to a `const`, meaning it can't be changed and having it have uninitialized values, there is no use for this sort of code and that is why it is forbidden. When you use the `mutable` keyword - it means that the value can be later changed, so the code can be used in a predictable manner.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb It seems to be a logical and touching answer. thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does C++ require a user-provided default constructor to default-construct a const object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411515/why-does-c-require-a-user-provided-default-constructor-to-default-construct-a)

Comment: @Does it? The OP are already aware that the first snippet is ill-formed, they wonder why clang accepts the second without any diagnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting my comment as an answer, hope it could helps someone.

It makes no sense declaring a const object if it is not initialized in some form.
Consider the following code:

```
    const int x;
```

**clang** says: `error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const int'`.
**gcc** would say: `error: uninitialized const ‘x’ [-fpermissive]`

The logic behind this is that there is no *sense* in this type of declaration.
The value of `x` can never change, and therefore this code would be unpredictable as `x` would be mapped to uninitialized memory.
In your example, adding the keyword `mutable` to `value` means that although the `Some` instance is constant when declared as:

```
    const Some some;
```

It is still possible to change `value` at a later time.
For example:

```
    some.value = 8;
```

This means it is possible to use this code in a predictable manner, since `value` can be set later, and there are no uninitialized constants.

Comment: If so, can we determine that there is a bug in gcc? When I compile the program with gcc, it reports an error even though the member variables are mutable.

Comment: Sorry @jinbeomhong - I don't know. I can only _guess_ the gcc team interprets the standard differently.