# Constant value calculation

Tags: c++

I have an hpp file with following code:

```
const float PixelsPerMeter = ConfigManager->Get<float>("koef", 100.0f);

inline const float Meters2Pixels(float meters) { return meters * PixelsPerMeter; }
inline const float Pixels2Meters(float pixels) { return pixels / PixelsPerMeter; }

const float ScreenArea = Pixels2Meters(ScreenSizeX) * Pixels2Meters(ScreenSizeY);
```

It worked before, but now `ScreenArea` = `inf` somehow. I use it from static function. I put a breakpoint in that function and print out the value of `PixelsPerMeter`(100.0), `ScreenSizeX` and `ScreenSizeY`. Everything is okay, but `ScreenArea` is calculated wrong.

When I write directly `Pixels2Meters(ScreenSizeX) * Pixels2Meters(ScreenSizeY)` instead of using `ScreenArea` constant everything works.

How it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the problem is with your global variable, to be precise with its initialization.

If by the  time the  variable has not been *dynamically* initialized when you call `Pixels2Meters()`, the variable `PixelsPerMeter` is *statically* initialized to zero, so the function `Pixels2Meters()` returns `inf` which very much implies `PixelsPerMeter` is zero.

But you put break points, the story could be slightly different; it is analogous to [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), in the sense that when you want to see the value of `PixelsPerMeter` by putting breakpoints, it shows you different value than the value when there is no breakpoints.

Also note that since the variable is declared `const`, without `extern` keyword, the variable has internal linkage, which means you will have different copy of this variable in each translation unit, in case if it declared in a header file which you include in several source files. The variable's behavior is as if it is declared `static`.

Another **important** point to be noted is that this variable is initialized twice: the first initialization is called *static initialization* which happens at compile-time, and second initialization is called *dynamic initialization* which happens at runtime. In case of *static initialization*, the variable is initialized to zero, and that is the value which is being used which is causing the problem. To know more about it, read this:

- [What is dynamic initialization of object in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945897/what-is-dynamic-intialization-of-object-in-c)

You should also read about this:

- [`static` initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)

Answer (score 0):

When the static function is initialised is a bit complicated and may depend on system/compiler.

You probably have an issue that the  ConfigManager() isn't initialised before the static function you are using it in.

Comment: As you understand, the second argument of `Get` from config is a default value in some extra cases. I tested it out (set not 100, but another value), and it's equal to 100 anyway, so, config manager works well there.