# Why C++ primitive types are not initialized like the rest of types?

Tags: c++, constructor, primitive, raii

I know that, in C++, when you write

```
int i;
```

you can not make any assumptions about the value that the variable will hold until you effectively assign it a value. However, if you write

```
int i = int();
```

then you have the guarantee that `i` will be `0`.  So my question is, isn't it actually an incosistency in the behavior of the language? I mean, if I have defined a class `MyClass` and write

```
MyClass myInstance;
```

I can rest assured that the default constructor without parameters of the class will be called to initialize `myInstance` (and the compiler will fail if there is none), because that's how the RAII principle goes. However, it seems that when it comes to primitive types, resource acquisition is not initialization anymore. Why is that?

I don't think that changing this behavior inherited from C would break any existing code (is there any code in the world that works on the assumption that no assumption can be made about the value of a variable?), so the main possible reason that comes to my mind is performance, for example when creating big arrays of primitive types; but still, I'd like to know if there is some *official* explanation to this.

Thanks.

Comment: "is there any code in the world that works on the assumption that no assumption can be made about the value of a variable?" Yes, for entropy pools.

Comment: I *think* you're looking at it from the wrong angle. Historically, variables were uninitialised, so the question should be why that changed for (some of) C++'s new class types, and that question is easier to answer. You're asking why the old types deviate from the norm, but the old types *were* the norm.

Comment: You could try to ask why MyClass(); is not required for the constructor to be called because it had resulted in more consistency in your view.

Comment: @Étienne Touché, cool example (although I hope they don't rely on uninitalized variables).

Comment: @user2672165 Your are right, but that's just because that way the compiler would confuse the object construction with a function declaration.

Comment: @javidcf Some implementations do rely on them as one source of entropy among several, see for instance http://lwn.net/Articles/586427/

Comment: @Étienne: This is a bad idea. This is considered undefined behavior by C standard, and [some implementations optimize this](http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It is not inconsistency.

What if your class is defined as:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int x;
    float y;
    char *z;
};
```

then this line does NOT do that you think it does:

```
MyClass myInstance;
```

Assuming the above is declared inside a function, it is same as:

```
int x; //assuming declared inside a function
```

In C++, the types are broadly divided into 3 kinds viz. POD, non-POD, Aggregates  — and there is a clear distinction between them. Please read about them and their initialization rules (there are too many topics on them. Search on this site). Also read about [*static initialization* and *dynamic initialization*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945897/what-is-dynamic-intialization-of-object-in-c).

Comment: shades of gray -- standard layout, aggregate... ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure aggregates are treated specially; aggregate initialization follows the rules of its members.  And it's not POD vs. non-POD; a class with virtual functions but no user defined constructors is not a POD, but it will be initialized as one.  And you've missed on of the most important differences: static lifetime vs. other lifetimes.

Comment: @JamesKanze: value initialization was introduced in C++03 (as the only new language feature, AFAIK) in order to clean up the initialization behavior for aggregates. in particular the non-POD ones. so there's special treatment.

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks. I've just found this reference covering several aspects about PODs and aggregates here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special and another about initialization here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402

Comment: @Alf The concept of value initialization was introduced in order to clarify issues that weren't clear in C++98.  It didn't actually change anything with regards to what had been the _intent_ (nor what compilers were actually doing in practice).

Answer (score 7):

The real reason, at least initially, was that C++ wanted all
objects which are compatible with C to behave exactly as they
would in C.  The reason in C *was* (and still is) performance;
zero initialization of objects with static lifetime was free
(because the OS must initialize all memory that it gives the
process anyway, for security reasons); zero initialization
otherwise costs runtime.  (The performance rationale is less
strong today than it was originally, because compilers are a lot
better at determining that the variable will be initialized
later, and suppressing the zero-initialization in such cases;
but they do still exist; in particular, in cases like:

```
char buffer[1000];
strcpy( buffer, something );
```

If zero initialization were required, I don't know of any
compiler which would be able to skip it here, even though it
won't be necessary.)

Comment: Also performance penalty for static initialization is likely to be smaller than for local variables as static initialization only happens once.

Comment: @user2672165 The performance penalty for zero initialization of statics is 0, at least on classical general purpose machines.

Comment: If strcpy() is inlined in your particular variant of C++ a good compiler may be able to optimize the initialization away. Otherwise: little chance that would happen.

Comment: @Tonny It would also have to prove that you never access beyond the trailing `'\0'`, because `strcpy` won't initialize these.

Answer (score 3):

If you write

```
int i;
```

then the initialization or not depends on the context.

- Namespace scope → zero-initialized.
- Local function scope → uninitialized.
- Class member: depends on the constructors, if any.

The lack of initialization for a local variable is just for efficiency. For a very simple function that is called repeatedly at the lowest levels, this can matter. And C and C++ are languages used to construct the bottom levels of things.

Comment: The initialization depends on object lifetime, _not_ scope.  Objects with static lifetime (even if they have local scope) are zero initialized before anything else (and this includes class members, even if the class has a constructor).

Comment: @JamesKanze: regarding the declaration `int i;` from the question and discussed in the answer, you're **wrong**. it can't be static unless it's in namespace scope , or in a static class type object (in which case it depends on constructors, if any). i understand that you're referring or *meant to refer* to variables in general, but by placing your remark as a comment on this answer it looks to readers like it contradicts something in the answer.

Comment: `void f() { static int i; /*...*/ }`.  The initialization does _not_ depend on the context; it depends on the object lifetime and the type of the object.  And of course, even in `class MyClass { int i; MyClass() {} };`, `MyClass:i` will be zero initialized in a static instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: note that you have introduced the keyword `static`, not present in the question or the answer. similarly, by introducing the keyword `unsigned` you can change some properties of the variable. and so on. generally, declarations change meaning as you add various keywords.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a local variable in a function to some value, then every time the function is called, the assignment takes place and the value is loaded into the stack.

For example:

```
void func()
{
    int i = 0; // Every time `func` is called, '0' is loaded into the stack
    ...
}
```

This is something that you might want to avoid, in particularly since the C and C++ languages are also designated for real-time systems, where every operation matters.

And by the way, when you declare `MyClass myInstance`, you can indeed rest assure that the default constructor is called, but you can choose whether or not you want to do anything in that constructor.

So the C and C++ languages allow you to make the same choice for primitive-type variables as well.

Comment: It's not the real time systems where it matters; it's ones which are CPU intensive (and which take a lot of time).

Comment: @JamesKanze I take it you never programmed on embedded real-time stuff ? Under tight conditions a couple of these might just make all the difference between being able to use a high level programming language and having to reach for assembler. Sometimes a few clock-cycles is all the leeway you have. You don't want any unneeded things happening behind your back. Granted: C++ isn't usually the language of choice for real-time stuff. It is usually C with additional tweaks and optimizations for the specific platform.

Comment: @Tonny Most of my early career was on embedded real-time stuff.  If things were that tight, we'd use a faster processor.  (There are exceptions, where I've had to juggle, but when I got to that point, I was writing in assembler.)  The important thing about real-time is that the response time have a deterministic upper bound.  So we'd use heap sort, instead of quick sort (supposing we had to sort, which I've never seen), despite the fact that heap sort is typically a lot slower.

Comment: @JamesKanze Seems we both started in the same business then. But were I was working a faster CPU usually didn't exist. So we often ended up looking at the assembler generated by the C compiler and then hand-optimizing that. (I did a lot of Hitachi H8 stuff. The compiler was very bad at optimizing.) Or we went asm all the way for the really critical parts.  I agree that determinism (and predictability) is everything in embedded real-time. Never had to sort either :-)