# Why can I initialize two static class variables in a single file out of order but not three?

Tags: c++

I was fooling around with static class variables, and I ran into something unexpected that I don't understand.

Stroustrup's book TC++PL4 says in 15.4.1 Initialization of Nonlocal Variables, "There is no guaranteed order of initialization of global variables in different translation units." But see that's for multiple translation units; I wasn't testing dependencies between files, this was in a single file. The same section says "In principle, a variable defined outside any function (that is, global, namespace, and class static variables) is initialized before `main()` is invoked. Such nonlocal variables in a translation unit are initialized in their definition order.

If I set up this at the top of the file:

```
class Test1 {
public:
static double test1;
};

class Test2 {
public:
static double test2;
};

class Test3 {
public:
static double test3;
};
```

I can do this:

```
double Test2::test2 = Test1::test1;
double Test1::test1 = 1.125;
```

And put this statement in main to check the values:

```
cout << Test1::test1 << " " << Test2::test2;
```

And both values will be 1.125.
I understand that both variables are in scope to be defined at that point, but if they are initialized in definition order how is it that a statement above is using the data from a statement below? Also, the order of class definitions at the top changes nothing in any of these cases.

If I use this arrangement:

```
double Test2::test2 = Test1::test1;
double Test3::test3 = Test2::test2;
double Test1::test1 = 1.125;
```

They will also all be 1.125.

But if I do this:

```
double Test3::test3 = Test2::test2;
double Test2::test2 = Test1::test1;
double Test1::test1 = 1.125;
```

`Test3::test3` will be 0.

It seems like it can look for another definition one layer in, but if that definition needs yet another definition it stops and just assigns zero. But I don't know what's really happening.

Does anyone know why it does this? I tried this in the C++ '14 mode of http://cpp.sh (GCC) and in VSE 2012 with consistent results.

EDIT: See, I keep seeing everywhere that you can't predict it, but this observation seems to be glossing over the apparent fact that there's a difference between uncertainty across files and the (possibly nonexistent?) uncertainty within a single file. Stroustrup basically said there's a difference, but static variables are weird.

I had a thought that it's possible that a class definition looks outside the original file to initialize the static data member even in the case of a single file so that in terms of the compilation logic the file loops around to find itself again, generating UB. If a compiler were programmed to assign zero instead of jumping to a third external variable the result would be predictable and more stable, but I don't have any proof that a file can externally reference itself like this.

EDIT 2: It appears to be a matter of static and dynamic initialization, where static initialization assigns zero or a given constant at compile time and dynamic then uses those values (like Mark B said) as in this:
[What is dynamic initialization of object in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945897/what-is-dynamic-initialization-of-object-in-c)
But I have to ask whether it's UB or not, still.

LAST EDIT: It wasn't hard to find information, the behavior is very well founded and not UB, see here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: just because the standard does not explicitly allow it, it does not mean that compilers cannot do it. Imho your results are completely consistent: If you stick to the rule everything is fine, if you dont sometimes you get `1.125` and sometimes `0`

Comment: @tobi303 are you saying this code contains undefined/unspecified /implementation-defined behaviour?

Comment: all static variables must be initialized before main call, but we cannot predict exact order of initialization (it is undifined).

Comment: @BryanChen for some reason i was assuming that they have to be defined in the order of declaration, but now I think I am completely wrong

Comment: See, I keep seeing everywhere that you can't predict it, but this observation seems to be glossing over the apparent fact that there's a difference between uncertainty across files and the (possibly nonexistent?) uncertainty within a single file. Stroustrup basically said there's a difference, but static variables are weird.

Comment: I had a thought that it's possible that a class definition looks outside the original file to initialize the static data member even in the case of a single file so that in terms of the compilation logic the file loops around to find itself again, generating UB.

Comment: Added, I'm new to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what's happening here is that there are effectively two phases of the initialization: static and dynamic. The compiler can see that `test1` is a constant and embeds that constant in the binary, default it to the value. It can't do so for `test2` and `test3`, so those get values of `0` in the binary.

Then before `main` starts up, the dynamic initialization phase starts, puts the 0 value from `test2` into `test3` and then the 1.25 constant from `test1` into `test2`.

All that said *never* rely on this and always initialize your variables in a sane order.

Comment: So there is no UB there?

Comment: This makes perfect sense! And, with that lead I found a LOT more information. This link here explains how the behavior is in the C++ standard from 2003: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945897/what-is-dynamic-initialization-of-object-in-c

Comment: But, I have to ask, given that the behavior seems so well-defined in the standard in terms of static and dynamic initialization with static being either 0 or a given constant, is this UB? It really doesn't actually look like UB. It's weird and impractical yes, but...

Comment: Appears to not be UB on further examination, thank you for helping!

Comment: [\[basic.start.init\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.init#3) grants extra leeway to the implementation here.