# How to change entry point of C program with gcc?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, entry-point

How to change the entry point of a C program compiled with gcc ?
Just like in the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int entry()  //entry is the entry point instead of main
 {
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @iandotkelly Not OP but I needed to use a checkpointing library which required me to change main() to something else ;)

Comment: @Nubcake Do you know the linker's option `--wrap=xxx`? It replaces all references of `xxx` by `__wrap_xxx` and all definitions of `xxx` by `__real_xxx`. I used it successfully for testing a `main()`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's a linker setting:

```
-Wl,-eentry
```

the `-Wl,...` thing passes arguments to the linker, and the linker takes a `-e` argument to set the entry function

Comment: This is what I got when I compiled a hello world C program with this option: `$ gcc  -Wl,-emymain t27.c 
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../crt1.o: In function '_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to 'main'`

Comment: @LeeDuhem, this is because you link your program with a standard c runtime library. An entry point in a program linked with c runtime library is _start. Start has a reference to main() of your program (it expects your program to have main() func instead of your custom func). Try not to link to a crt and specify an entry point as your_main and see what happens.

Comment: @LeeDuhem, -nostdlibs that flag is.

Comment: `-nostartfiles` is the actual flag you want, this omits the crt*.o files containing _start, but still allows you to use a libc (unless you also use -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs, in which case you can still manually specify them using -lc -lgcc etc...)

Comment: I believe there is a typo:
should be `-Wl,--entry="MyCutomEntryFunction"`
or `-Wl,-e="MyCutomEntryFunction"`

Comment: @RomainVIOLLETTE it works fine for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613764/895245 on Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 10):

If you are on a system that provides [GNU Binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) (like Linux),
you can use the `objcopy` command
to make an arbitrary function the new entry point.

Suppose a file called `program.c` containing the `entry` function:

```
$ cat > program.c
#include <stdio.h>
int entry()
{
    return 0;
}
^D
```

1. You first compile it using `-c` to generate a relocatable object file:

   ```
   $ gcc -c program.c -o program.o
   ```
2. Then you redefine `entry` to be `main`:

   ```
   $ objcopy --redefine-sym entry=main program.o
   ```
3. Now use gcc to compile the new object file:

   ```
   $ gcc program.o -o program
   ```

**NOTE:** If your program already has a function called `main`, before step 2, you can perform a separate `objcopy` invocation:

```
objcopy --redefine-sym oldmain=main program.o
```

Answer (score 9):

You can modify your source code as:

```
#include<stdio.h>

const char my_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib/ld-linux.so.2";

int entry()  //entry is the entry point instead of main
{
   exit(0);
}
```

The ".interp" section will let your program able to call external shared library.
The exit call will make your entry function to exit program instead of return.

Then build the program as a shared library which is executable:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -e entry test_main.c -o test_main.so
$ ./test_main
```

Comment: What is the calling convention of the `entry` function? Is the C-runtime initialized in this way?

Comment: could you please explain what this mean *"build the program as a **shared library** which is **executable**"* How can it be both?

Comment: @harper: It's not a C compatible calling convention. The ELF entry point ABI has its primary argument in the stack pointer, pointing to an "array" consisting of argc, argv pointers, null, env pointers, null, aux vector table. Some archs have additional args in specific registers.

Comment: doesn't work.. I get: **cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

Answer (score 3):

**Minimal runnable example and notes on other answers**

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mymain(void) {
    puts("hello");
    exit(0);
}
```

compile and run:

```
gcc -nostartfiles -Wl,--entry=mymain -o main.out main.c
# or -Wl,-emymain
./main.out 1 2 3
```

The notes:

- without `-nostartfiles`, the link fails with:

  ```
  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
  (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  ```

  presumably because the glibc setup code that [runs before main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783404/is-main-really-start-of-a-c-program) in `_start` normally calls `main`.
- command line arguments are not setup for you, presumably because they would be setup by the glibc code that runs before main, so trying to use them prints undefined values. I haven't found a method that works for them.

Tested in Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Does not work, apparently the warning is serious.

Comment: @ScottFranco what's your GCC version/OS version BTW?

Comment: C:\projects\petit_ami>gcc -v
...
gcc version 9.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC Build-2)

Comment: @ScottFranco the warning was caused by small typo `-eentry=` should have been `--entry=` ; I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Demi-Lune nice catch! I wonder how it worked with the typo at all on my test!

Comment: @Self: it worked before by coincidence because it was the first thing in the text section