# C defining macro which would be processed only once and not recursively

Tags: c, unix

I want to change main so that it calls one function before doing anything else. So I written code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    printf("\nTEST\n");
#undef main
    main(1,NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
}
```

and compiled it like

```
cc -g -Dmain=test test.c -o test
```

but still it prints "Hello World" and not "TEST".
What should I do so that I can call test just before main does anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just call the function first thing you do in `main`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-the-entry-point-in-gcc tells you how to change the entry point with gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want call other function, before main, gcc provides `__attribute__`

for example:

```
int test(void) __attribute__ ((constructor));

int test()
{
    printf("\nTEST\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```