# gcc with linker option e gets segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault

Here is my program:

```
void f(){
    printf("here\n");
}
void main(){
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc -ef *.c`. When I run it gives the following output:

```
here
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The backtrace shows this:

```
#0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffffffdf9e in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: When you see a useless backtrace like that,  you should add `-g` to our compiler options and try again.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I tried with -g too. It shows the same backtrace. Could you suggest anything more?

Comment: You are compiling *all* C files in the current directory with `*.c`. We don't know what you have in those files. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @l3x I am compiling the only file in the directory. You can replace * with <filename> and it gives the same result. I have alread given the minimal verifiable code.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-entry-point-of-c-program-with-gcc

Comment: @JohnZwinck I tried both `-Wl` and 'interp'. It is still the same.

Comment: is there any reason to prefer `void main() {}` over `int main(void) {}` ? (short answer: there isn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the default entry point of the executable, which is typically `_start`.  `_start` does some things for you: setting up the C runtime environment, grabbing argv, and calling libc_start_main which will *exit with process using exit()* when `main()` returns (among many other things).  Your program needs to call `exit()` to properly leave the process... otherwise, you're returning to nowhere.

Just for reference, you can find the `exit()` call in glibc [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/libc-start.c;h=0afa7c01ba39083652d03449382d67300a66597f;hb=HEAD#l323).