# Error Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c, reference, undefined

Can a program be written without `main()` function?

I have written this code and saved a filename as `withoutmain.c`
and getting an error as

```
undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"
```

My code

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<windows.h>
    extern void _exit(register int code);
    _start(){
      int retval;
      retval=myFunc();
      _exit(retval);
    }
    int myFunc(void){
     printf("Hiii Pratishtha");
     return 0;
    }
```

Please provide me the solution of this problem and also the proper memory construction of code and what is happening at the compiler end of this program.
Thank you!

Comment: The solution is simple: do not write a program without `main()`.

Comment: There must be a way to specify the entry point in your linker options, but for gcc I don't know it. Why don't you look it up in the documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change entry point of C program with gcc ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-entry-point-of-c-program-with-gcc)

Comment: If your question is Windows-specific, at least tag it as such (and in fact, specify your compilation environment - which compiler etc). The answer is markedly different if you are asking a general C question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a program be written without main() function?

Yes there can be a C program without a main function.
I would suggest two solutions.......

**1) Using a macro that defines main**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#define _start main
extern void _exit(register int code);

int myFunc(void){
    printf("Hiii Pratishtha");
    return 0;
}

int _start(){
     int retval;
     retval=myFunc();
     _exit(retval);
}
```

**2) [Using Entry Point (Assuming you are using visual studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx)**

To set this linker option in the Visual Studio development environment

```
/ENTRY:function
```

A function that specifies a user-defined starting address for an .exe file or DLL.

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see
   Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.
2. LClick the Linker folder.
3. Click the Advanced property page.
4. Modify the Entry Point property.

**OR**

if you are using `gcc` then

```
-Wl,-e_start
```

the `-Wl`,... thing passes arguments to the linker, and the linker takes a `-e` argument to set the entry function