# Segmentation fault when using custom entry point

Tags: c, gcc, entry-point

After having read this: [How to change entry point of C program with gcc ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-entry-point-of-c-program-with-gcc)

I tested the answer with this code:

```
int entry()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Then I compiled it with gcc:

```
gcc -Wl,--entry=entry -nostartfiles custom_entry.c
```

It successfully compiles, but when I try to run it I get a segmentation fault. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Try exiting with `exit(10);` instead of `return 10;`

Comment: That worked, thank you!