# Linking 2 object files in c to create an executable

Tags: c, makefile, object-files

I am having an issue with a makefile for something I am making. My makefile looks like this

```
bag: main.o bow.o
    gcc bow.o main.o -o bag
main.o: main.c bow.h
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.c -o main.o
bow.o: bow.c bow.h
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c bow.c -o -bow.o
```

I also have a header file called "bow.h" that is used in both bow.o and main.o. bow.h consists of 8 function definitions and 2 structs, bow.c contains the 8 functions and NO MAIN file. main.c is suppose to be a minimal main file so it only consists of

```
#include "bow.h"
```

When I run my makefile in the Terminal with

```
make
```

I get this message

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'bag' failed
make: *** [bag] Error 1
```

What exactly does this mean, how is it caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do any of the source files contain a `main` function? you do know that a C program *must* have a `main` **function**, as that's where the execution start? The error message simply says that the linker can't find the `main` function.

Comment: Not according to `main.c is suppose to be a minimal main file so it only consists of

#include "bow.h"`

Comment: main.c needs a `main` function (that calls one or more of the functions in bow.c), and the line that compiles main.c needs a `-c` option.

Comment: "bow.c contains ... and NO MAIN file." Do you mix up "file" and "function"? What is a minimal main file if there is no main function in it? There is no such thing as a "main file" in C. All files are same. It all depents on the definitiones inside.

Answer (score 2):

Even a minimal program (executable) needs a point to start. For a C program, this is the `main()` function. Thus, the linker seeks for that function (more precisely, it links the start-up object where `main` is an unresolved symbol), does not find it, and issues an error.

Thus, you have to provide a `main()`. Alternatively, you may not generate an executable but a library.

Comment: This is right answer, however for advanced users, this is partially true. Default is `main()`, but it is possible to modify an entry point (for whatever reason). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-entry-point-of-c-program-with-gcc

Comment: You are right, but this is a compiler feature. The C standard say that ˋmain()ˋ is called at startup (cf. eg. C11 5.1.2.2.1).

Comment: Good to know! Thanks.