How to run multiple functions in one file (C++)
So this seems to be a frequently asked question but on more complex problems. I am just starting out and am coming from a higher level language (python) and thus a bit confused as to what C++ wishes me to specify. I have 2 virtually identical functions and when I run the file it seems to just output one of them and I am not sure why not both. It seems to be something with the naming. C++ seems to want to prefer things named as main().
I feel for someone with experience this may be quite obvious and I would be thrilled to also have some more details about the goings on of C++ and how/why it determines what functions to "prefer". (I am using a VScode environment)
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int starter()
{
    //declaring variables
    int a, b;
    int result;

    // process
    a = 5;
    b = 2;
    a = a + 1;
    result = a - b;

    //print the result
    cout << result;

    //terminate the program
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    int a = 5; //"c-like"
    int b (3); // "constructor"
    int c {1}; // "uniform"
    int result; //initial value undetermined

    result = a + b - c;

    cout << result;

    return 0;
}

Only the main(){} block of code is executed

Yes, it always runs main, and you must have exactly one main. You could call starter(); from main.

Any beginners book or tutorial should have taught you this in the first few paragraphs. The main function is the one that will be called when the program starts. Always. If you need to "run" other functions, you have to call them. Just like you do in just about every other language (even in Python).

Also, even python doesn't just randomly run all the functions that it finds in the source code...

"C++ seems to want to prefer things named as main()" - Trial and error is not a good way to learn C++. This might help: The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List.

ah great to know, thank you. It is interesting to me that if I put a "cout << starter();" or a "int x {starter()};" statement both times the functions is also actually executed before being passed to the operator/variable. Is there a convention on how to call functions in main to avoid problems with this? (i saw just writing "starter();" works fine) (I guess this would usually not be an issue with a function lacking print commands)

maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-entry-point-of-c-program-with-gcc

Thanks a lot for all the replies. I was using the cpluplus documentation to help myself along and got sidetracked on the way. I will e sure to check out the suggested resources :)

From the C++23 draft [basic.start.main]:

6.9.3.1



A program shall contain exactly one function called main that belongs to the global scope. Executing a program starts a main thread of execution ([intro.multithread], [thread.threads]) in which the main function is invoked.




That's all there is to it. Other functions you wish to be invoked can be called from main either directly or indirectly.
You can also call functions to initialize global variables.
#include <iostream>

int starter()
{
    // ...
    return 123;
}

int x = starter(); // called before `main`

int main()
{
    std::cout << x << '\n'; // prints 123
}

