# Why statements cannot appear at namespace scope?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, standards

Any idea on which rule in standard states the statements like this:

```
p++; //where 'p' is pointer to array
```

cannot appear in global scope?

I'm looking for a reference not just an explanation if possible.

Comment: isn't it just declarations that can have global scope?

Comment: When would you expect such a statement to run?

Comment: I was excepting the value to be discarded if not left operand is available but this gives me an error, but it seems there's no where mentioned that they cannot appear in global scope.

Comment: `p++` doesn't just assign to an lvalue (if one were present), it also increments the value of `p`, so that goes back to @JamesMcNellis' comment.

Comment: @JimBuck: no integral expressions either,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The expression `p++` which you've written is at namespace scope.  It is forbidden by the grammer of *namespace-body* which is defined in §7.3.1/1 as:

> namespace-body:
>        declaration-seq<sub>opt</sub>

which says the namespace-body can *optionally* contain **only** *declaration*. And `p++` is surely not a declaration, it is an expression, therefore the Standard implicitly forbids it. The Standard might have explicit statement forbidding this, but I think the above should be enough.

In the same way, you **cannot** do this:

```
namespace sample
{
  f(10,10); //error
  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;//error
}
```

But if you somewhow convert *expressions* into *declarations* (or rather *use* expressions in declarations), then you could evaluate the so-called expressions. Here is one trick:

```
#include<iostream>

namespace sample
{
  struct any { template<typename T> any(const T&){} };

  void f(int a,int b) { std::cout << a * b <<  std::endl; }

  any a1= (f(10,10), 0); //ok
  any a2 = std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;//ok
}

int main() {}
```

Output (if you're lucky):

```
100
hello world
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/icbhh

Notice that the return type of `f()` is `void`, which means I cannot write the following ([see error)](http://ideone.com/YmGpg):

```
any a1 = f(10,10); //error
```

That is why I used *comma* operator so that the expression could have some value, which evaluates to the last operand in the comma expression. In case of `std:cout`, since it returns `std::ostream&`, I don't need to use comma operator; it is fine without it.

One more interesting thing in the above code: why I defined `any` and a *templated* constructor in it? The answer is, I wrote this so that I could assign value of *any* type (no pun intended), be it `int`, `std::ostream&` or whatever. The *templated* constructor can take argument of any type.

**But don't write such code. They're not guaranteed to work the way you expect.**

Read the answers in this topic where you would see why such coding could be dangerous:

- [Is main() really start of a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783404/is-main-really-start-of-a-c-program)

Comment: "They're not guaranteed to work the way you expect" - unless you know the way they're guaranteed to work. In which case they work exactly the way you'd expect, but woe betide if you have more than one translation unit.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Also, I said that specifically because of `std::cout`, as it might not have been *fully* initialized (with all its dependencies) by the time when `operator<<` is invoked on it.

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't know what the standard says about when `std::cout` becomes ready for use. In practice implementations seem to do backflips where necessary to make it available as soon as humanly possible.

Comment: The grammar *namespace-body* is not referenced for global namespace. For global namespace, the grammar [*translation-unit*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/gram#nt:translation-unit) applies instead.

Answer (score 0):

By saying "statements like this" I guess you know that/why statements in general cannot be in global scope.

```
p++;
```

Is a statement because it basically is translated into:

```
p = p + 1;
```

Which is a normal statement.

Answer (score 0):

CHeck out "The C++ programming Language" by of course Stroustrup.

Section r.6.1 talks about statements - which can be labels, expressions, compound statements, selection statements, iteration statements, jump statements or declaration statements.

Then jump back to section 3.3.1 Which shows the statement syntax and references:
Note that.....there is no assignment statement or procedure call statement.  Assignment and function call are handled as expressions.

Section r.3.1 then talks about four types of scope - local, function, file and class.  Since global is essentially "file" scope.  Names are allowed in global scope as are classes first declared in a return or argument type.

Really could find no concrete definitive that flat out states you can't have an expression statement in global scope, but by omission the references show what you CAN have.