# global variable initialization

Tags: c++

In principle, a variable defined outside any function (that is, global, namespace, and class static variables) is initialized before `main()` is invoked. Such nonlocal variables in a translation unit are initialized in their declaration order

Above are the lines from the class notes given by my lecturer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int a=99;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  cout<<a<<endl;
  cout<<b<<endl;
  return 0;
}
int b=100;
```

There is an error while I run this. Isn't it true that `b` assigned to `100` before `main()` is called?

Comment: can you post the exact compilation error

Comment: You're getting confused between initialisation order and compilation order - they are not the same thing.

Comment: So,is it like,Compilation is done line by line in order.When compilation reaches cout<<b<<endl; line,it doesn't know what 'b' is.Is this the reason why there is an error here? After the program is compiled,at execution time,'b' would be initialized before main() is called.Is it so?plz clarify,though it miight be silly

Comment: @tez: yes, that's more or less correct - you need to declare `b` before you use it so that the compiler "sees" its declaration first.

Comment: @PaulR:Please have a look at the edited code

Comment: @tez: that is still not correct - you need `extern int b;` above `main` and `int b = 100;` below `main`.

Comment: Because [expression statements are not allowed in namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8470186/5376789).

Comment: The question is largely change by the 4th edit (by OP), I'd suggest rollback it.

Comment: I edited the question to match most of the answers (and the accepted one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is not initialisation order: `b` is indeed initialised before `main` starts running.

The problem is the "visibility" of `b`. At the point where `main` is being compiled, there *is* no `b`.

You can fix it by either moving the definition/initialisation of `b` to before `main`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int a = 99;
int b = 100;
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << a << '\n';
    cout << b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

or simply indicate that `b` exists:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int a = 99;
extern int b;
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << a << '\n';
    cout << b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
int b = 100;
```

Neither of those two solutions change when `b` is created or initialised at run-time, they simply make `b` available within `main`.

Answer (score 4):

Your lecturer is wrong; global variables are initialised in order of *definition*, not *declaration*.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
struct S { S(const char *s) { std::cout << s << '\n'; } };
extern S a;    // declaration
extern S b;    // declaration
int main() { }
S b("b");      // definition
S a("a");      // definition
```

will print

```
b
a
```

The code you posted doesn't work because `b` is not even *declared* at the point of use.  A declaration (for example, `extern int b`), is required because C++ (like C) was originally designed as a [one-pass compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_compiler).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: `cout<<b<<endl;`

You can't access the variable before it's declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully.

A variable defined outside any function (B) is initialized before main is invoked (not compiled).

To be compiled correctly B should be defined(and declared) before it's first use (and that's your error: B is used before been declared anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the statement `b=100;`: you can't place a statement in a global scope (except for variable initialization).

If this line remains as is, the code won't compile regardless of `b` declarations/definitions or the use of `b` within `main` or anywhere.

Without this line, the code is correct and works, with `b` value equals `0`, since uninitialized global variables are initialized to 0 (or the line `b=100;` could be moved into any function scope).