# Error : Expected a declaration

Tags: visual-c++

I am writing a code in Visual C++ to access serial port.

Code is given below:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef __CAPSTONE_CROSS_SERIAL_PORT__
#define __CAPSTONE_CROSS_SERIAL_PORT__
HANDLE hSerial= CreateFile(L"COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
 //serial port does not exist. Inform user.
 }
 //some other error occurred. Inform user.
 }
```

In the above code I am getting error at **if** in line

```
if(hserial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

Error is given below:-

```
Error:expected a declaration
```

I am getting same error at both braces **}** at the end of **if** statement

I want to know why I am getting this error and how to resolve it

Comment: You're writing code in random places. Shouldn't that be in a method or class or something?

Comment: In addition to that, you'll require `#include <windows.h>`.  And most of the support code you do have is unneeded or outright wrong.  You can't expect a Frankenstein to work properly, not in C++.  You need some basic understanding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470065/why-statements-cannot-appear-at-namespace-scope).  The problem is you are trying to use an `if` statement at namespace scope (global namespace) where only a declaration is valid.

You will need to wrap your logic in a function of some kind.

```
void mySuperCoolFunction()
{
  if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
       //serial port does not exist. Inform user.
    }
    //some other error occurred. Inform user.
  }
}
```