# Modifying Static Member after Initialization

Tags: c++

I'm having a strange issue where I'm unable to modify one of the static members of a class after initializing the class. Here's the code I have:

**my_values.hpp**

```
#include "weird_class.hpp"
namespace foo {
class Bar {
 public:
  static WeirdClass weird_class_obj;
};
```

**my_values.cpp**

```
#include "weird_class.hpp"
#include "my_values.hpp"
namespace foo {
  WeirdClass Bar::weird_class_obj = WeirdClass(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
  Bar::weird_class_obj.set_weird_value(100.0f);
}
```

**weird_class.hpp**

```
#ifndef WEIRD_CLASS_H
#define WEIRD_CLASS_H
class WeirdClass {
public:
 WeirdClass(float, float, float, float);
 void set_weird_value(float);
private:
 float weird_value;
};
#endif
```

**weird_class.cpp**

```
#include "weird_class.hpp"
void WeirdClass::set_weird_value(float weirdValue) {
  weird_value = weirdValue;    
}
```

If I comment out line 5 in `my_values.cpp` the files compile fine. But if I don't, the error I get is

```
error: no type named 'weird_class_obj' in 'foo::Bar' Bar::weird_class_obj.set_weird_value(100.0f);
                                                          ^
error: cannot use dot operator on a type Bar::weird_class_obj.set_weird_value(100.0f);
                                                             ^
```

My guess is that `weird_class_obj` is somehow being treated as a type rather than an object of class `WeirdClass`. But why would this be?

Comment: You cannot call member functions out of a namespace scope. Why do you need to reset it anyways? Just initialize it properly inside the constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why statements cannot appear at namespace scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470065/why-statements-cannot-appear-at-namespace-scope)

Comment: @Jodocus thanks. This example is a stripped-down version of my actual code, where WeirdClass is actually a PID controller library (that I didn't write, and ideally I shouldn't modify) and weirdValue is an additional configuration parameter that I have to set separately from the constructor. I do have another place to do all that configuration in, though, so things should work out. Thanks for alerting me to the namespace problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that you may not modify the object. The problem is you placed this:

```
Bar::weird_class_obj.set_weird_value(100.0f);
```

An executable statement, into namespace scope. That's just not allowed.

If the c'tor of `WeirdClass` is that weird that you may not set the value in it, but the class is not so weird as to disallow copying/moving, you can use the following trick:

```
WeirdClass Bar::weird_class_obj = []() {
  WeirdClass obj(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
  obj.set_weird_value(100.0f);
  return obj;
}();
```

The above is known in the JavaScript world as an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). If you can't do that for whatever reason, then a named free function can be used for the same purpose as well.