# Call a function before main

Tags: c++, c, startup, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is main() really start of a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783404/is-main-really-start-of-a-c-program)

Is possible to call my function before program's startup? How can i do this work in `C++` or `C`?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you cannot just make the call immediately after entering main() but before any of your other code executes?  Why is pre-main() a requirement?

Comment: why not call this function at main begin?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? If you further explain your actual problem you might get suggestions on the design (rather than the technique). While you can do what you ask for, I would rethink a design that depends on this.

Comment: The answers you got will do what you want but be aware that order of evaluation isn't well defined so if you have two of them there is no telling which will run first, so making one of them depend on the results of the other is bad things waiting to happen.  This bug is so common it has its own name: the static order initialization fiasco.

Comment: I was reading about logger and I thought it was usefu know how start a method before the program starts.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can have a global variable or a `static` class member.

**1) `static` class member**

```
//BeforeMain.h
class BeforeMain
{
    static bool foo;
};

//BeforeMain.cpp
#include "BeforeMain.h"
bool BeforeMain::foo = foo();
```

**2) global variable**

```
bool b = foo();
int main()
{
}
```

Note this link - [Mirror of http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14](http://dietmar-kuehl.de/mirror/c++-faq/ctors.html#faq-10.14) / [proposed alternative](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) - posted by Lundin.

Comment: Note: the `class` itself is spurious here, just building a global (whatever) is sufficient.

Comment: Just be aware of [this subtle bug](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14). The function called cannot be allowed to depend on any static resources. You should write it as you would write a re-entrant function.

Comment: I believe this to be technically incorrect. AFAIR the function is not required to be called before `main` and can be delayed until `b` is needed. Or maybe it was just the observable state had to be the same.

Comment: @Pubby I believe that actually the order is enforced, but granted I'm not going to look for the quote in the standard. :)

Comment: An additional warning, if that code ever lands in a static linux library (lib*.a): if not told otherwise the linker will ignore any unused variable including initialisation -> foo() will never be called.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that is a bug that bit me twice before, and it's really easy to forget not to use any of your `extern`'d globals (they will be 0's, not the initial values you give them in some other .cpp)

Comment: Incorrect: Since `b` is never used, **the compiler is free to never call** `b = foo()`. Only guarantee is that `b = foo()` is called before `b`'s first use, not before `main`.

Comment: @cz including the case where foo() has side-effects?

Answer (score 38):

In `C++` there is a simple method: **use the constructor of a global object**.

```
class StartUp
{
public:
   StartUp()
   { foo(); }
};

StartUp startup; // A global instance

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

This because the global object is constructed before `main()` starts. As *Lundin* pointed out, pay attention to the [*static initialization order fiasco*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: Any part of the initialization, really, including arguments passed to a constructor.

Comment: Just be aware of [this subtle bug](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14). The function called cannot be allowed to depend on any static resources. You should write it as you would write a re-entrant function.

Answer (score 25):

If using `gcc` and `g++` compilers then this can be done by using `__attribute__((constructor))`

eg::
In gcc (c) ::

```
#include <stdio.h>

void beforeMain (void) __attribute__((constructor));

void beforeMain (void)
{
  printf ("\nbefore main\n");
}

int main ()
{
 printf ("\ninside main \n");
 return 0;
}
```

In g++ (c++) ::

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void beforeMain (void) __attribute__((constructor));

void beforeMain (void)
{
  cout<<"\nbefore main\n";
}

int main ()
{
  cout<<"\ninside main \n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except this isn't C nor C++, it is GCC non-standard extensions.

Comment: I had a need to call a `void function` before main recently, and tried adapting this answer, but it crashed. I tested at cpp.sh as well as code chef: same result both cases. If I use printf instead of cout, there is no crash. Any idea why?

Comment: @StoneThrow I suspect your function was called before `cout` was constructed.

Answer (score 21):

In C++ it is possible, e.g.

```
static int dummy = (some_function(), 0);

int main() {}
```

In C this is not allowed because initializers for objects with static storage duration must be constant expressions.

Comment: In C there is not a way? Only in C++?

Comment: @Nick: yes, as far as I know.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: You can make it work in C as well: `static size_t dummy = sizeof(some_function(), 0);`

Comment: @Nawaz: Does that work?  I was under the impression that `sizeof` didn't evaluate its argument. (http://ideone.com/dG62n)

Comment: @Nawaz What Oli said, `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its argument, unless it is a variable length array.

Comment: @Nawaz, initializations of `static` variables must be constant expressions that are not evaluated. This doesn't work at all.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Oops... that just skipped my mind..

Comment: @CBBailey, sorry, why doesn't it work in C and it does in C++?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to refer this link..

http://bhushanverma.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-call-function-before-main-and.html

For GCC compiler on Linux/Solaris:

```
#include

void my_ctor (void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
void my_dtor (void) __attribute__ ((destructor));

void
my_ctor (void)
{
printf ("hello before main()\n");
}

void
my_dtor (void)
{
printf ("bye after main()\n");
}

int
main (void)
{
printf ("hello\n");
return 0;
}

$gcc main.c
$./a.out
hello before main()
hello
bye after main()
```