# Hello world with only return in main

Tags: c++, puzzle

What is the way to write a program meeting following requirements:

1. Prints "Hello world!" to stdout;
2. Has empty main (just returning 0) i.e.

   ```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. `main` must contain no additional code except for that above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897552/call-a-function-before-main?lq=1

Comment: Welcome to SO. The idea is that you try to solve this yourself, and when you encounter a specific problem, you ask a question, showing relevant code.

Comment: Googling "Hello World" C gave me 37,000,000 hits. Were they all useless?

Comment: You might want to clarify the requirement that you print the text without any code in main, as many will not spot that.

Comment: @NeilKirk so I did. I guess, I'll just accept what seems best answer and be more constructive next time.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It might take quite a while to read through 37,000,000 examples to discover whether any of them have an empty `main`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in different ways. Consider you have `#include <iostream>` then following methods should be placed before main.

1. You may use macros, but the result is undefined as noticed in comments. So even if this is an easy way, it should never be used. I will still leave it here for completeness.

   ```
   #define return std::cout << "Hello world!"; return
   ```
2. You may use static variable:

   ```
   int helloWorld() 
   { 
       std::cout << "Hello World"; 
       return 0; 
   }
   static int print = helloWorld();
   ```
3. ... or even simpler:

   ```
   bool printed = std::cout << "Hello World";
   ```
4. You can do same with object:

   ```
   struct hello
   {
       public:
           hello()
           {
               std::cout << "Hello, world!";
           }
   } world;
   ```

Comment: Note that the behavior of option 1 is undefined.

Comment: @PeteBecker, good point, will update.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Bob
{
    Bob()
    {
        printf("Hello world!");
    }
} bob;

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Object Instantiation:

   ```
   struct S
   {
       S() { std::cout << "Hello World!"; }
   } s;

   int main() { }
   ```
2. Or in an expression:

   ```
   int i = ((std::cout << "Hello World\n"), 5);

   int main() { }
   ```