# Where is the main function in a wxWidgets application?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I try to use wxWidgets in my C++ project.
As far as I know, for wxWidgets I need to use `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyAPP );`
instead of the `main()` function.
I don't understand how to write other functions to do other work before my wxWidgets graphics object is created.
In other words, I would like to understand how to get a result like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    configure_application_1();
    app_config app_cfg;
    app_configuration(app_cfg); 
    
    other_functions();

    ___create_wxWidgets________

}
```

Comment: The question title seems unrelated to question description.

Comment: Just create a global instance of something, and do work in its constructor function. Better leave the `main()` implementation to the wxWidgets framework.

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897552/call-a-function-before-main

Comment: @SuperPuper, first - there is no such thing as `create wxWidgets`. Sercond - did you try to buyild and run `minimal` sample and look at its code? Are you trying to learn C++?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official doc](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_app.html):

> A wxWidgets application does not have a main procedure; the equivalent
> is the wxApp::OnInit member defined for a class derived from wxApp.

So put your code in `wxApp::OnInit` function.

Answer (score 2):

The `main()`, or `WinMain()` (or other entry points that used to exist, but don't any more because the corresponding platforms have gone extinct), is part of [wxIMPLEMENT_APP()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/interface_2wx_2app_8h.html#a967aafaa261481fe2d2e1cf599e3e003) macro expansion. If you don't want it to define your entry point, you can use `wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN()`, but then you're responsible for initializing the library yourself.

However typically you would just leave it be and put your initialization code in your overridden `MyApp::OnInit()`, where `MyApp` is your class inheriting from `wxApp`.