# How to execute a function before `main` without use a variable?

Tags: c++

In file src.cpp

```
void initz()
{
    // ...
}
```

I want execute this function when the .exe start,before 'int main()',
so i use

```
void initz()
{
    // ...
}
initz();
```

but it can't compile success.
I know i can use

```
int initz()
{
    // ...
}
static int a = initz();
```

but this will create a new variable 'a',
although it will not add a new symbol to the linker(can't use outside the .obj file)
.but it seems not a good solation.

**very important**
How to avoid create the new variable 'a'?
I don't want to use anymore memory space to execute the function.
i think it's no necessory.

Comment: What's wrong with calling `initz();` as the first line inside the body of `main`?

Comment: I hope this function can called before int main(),just call it in c++ initializer(can't use in c)

Comment: If you want a solution that also works in C, edit the question to specify as such. If you want a non-standard way to run code before `main`, with GCC you may use [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2053029/12122460).

Comment: Could you clarify why you feel that having an additional static variable is not a good solution?

Comment: Why does it have to be executed before `main`? If you can describe that, perhaps there are alternative ways of doing what you need to do.

Comment: [Call a function before main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897552/call-a-function-before-main).

Comment: I think this is an XY-problem. What are you trying to achieve and why?