# Difference between "return 0" and "exit (0)"

Tags: c, function

Is there any difference between `return 0` and `exit (0)` when using in a function?
If yes, When should I use `return 0` or `exit (0)` in a function?

Comment: exit 0? probably doesn't compile. exit(0) exits your program. You probably don't want that

Comment: Sorry for that.I have edited the question.

Comment: There is a similar post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116493/how-to-quit-a-c-program

Comment: Was it really that hard to write a 10-line code to try it yourself?

Comment: Not sure why people use return(x) when return is not a function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161879/parenthesis-surrounding-return-values

Comment: @Arthur "try it" is often a bad way to fully understand C, and I think this is one of that cases. About the question, they are different even in `main`, look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262698/can-main-return-structure/17262704#comment25021781_17262704) comments.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`return` exits from the function while `exit` exits from the program.

In `main` function executing `return 0;` statement or calling `exit(0)` function will call the registered `atexit` handlers and will cause program termination.

Comment: The `atexit` handlers get called when returning from main, too.

Answer (score 12):

`exit 0` is a syntax error in C. You can have `exit(0)` that is instead a call to a standard library function.

The function `exit` will quit the whole program, returning the provided exit code to the OS. The `return` statement instead only quits the current function giving the caller the specified result.

They are the same only when used in `main` (because quitting the `main` function will terminate the program).

Normally `exit` is only used in emergency cases where you want to terminate the program because there's no sensible way to continue execution. For example:

```
//
// Ensure allocation of `size` bytes (will never return
// a NULL pointer to the caller).
//
// Too good to be true? Here's the catch: in case of memory
// exhaustion the function will not return **at all** :-)
//
void *safe_malloc(int size) {
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory: quitting\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}
```

In this case if function `a` calls function `b` that calls function `c` that calls `safe_malloc` you may want to quit the program on the spot instead of returning to `c` an error code (e.g. a `NULL` pointer) if the code is not written to handle allocation failures.

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is, since there is no statement called `exit`. I guess you mean the *function* [`exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit)?

In that case, there is a *big* difference: The `exit` function exits the process, in other words the program is terminated. The `return` *statement* simply return from the current function.

They are only similar if used in the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

- `return` is a statement that returns control back to the calling
  function.
- `exit` is a system call which terminates the current process i.e the
  currently executing program.

In `main()` the `return 0;` and `exit(0);` perform the same thing.

NOTE: you have to include `#include<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: *"Some compilers even accept and compile the code even if u dont write return 0"* because it's standard.