# implict intialized variable not in .bss section

Tags: c, gcc, arm

[Compiler gcc-arm-8.2-2019.01]

I have a variable in .c:`int ep;`I expect it is put in .bss section and having 0 initial value, but it is excluded from .bss section after I check the .map file.
If I change the line to:
`int ep = 0;`
The var is put into .bss section.
My guess is compiler found that the var is a **writeonly**, so no need initialize its value to 0.
But this var is read by assembly code, also read by another program, which compiler seems not knowing and make the wrong optimize choice.

Any help on this behavior?

---

excluded from .bss means, in linkscript file I write:

```
        .bss :
        {   
                . = ALIGN(64);
                __bss_start = .;
                *(.bss)
                *(.bss.*)
                __bss_end = .;
        } > DRAM
```

but var `ep` is not between `__bss_start` and `__bss_end`, where assembly code use them to do memory clear before jump in C code

Comment: Are you looking at where it is in the object file, or in the executable?  For the former, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835716/bss-vs-common-what-goes-where/16836156#16836156 (note that `-fcommon` is no longer the default from gcc 10 onward).  If the executable, try `objdump --syms` on it and show us the line with `ep`.

Comment: use objdump --syms for .elf file, it shows ```ep``` is in .bss section:
 g     O .bss   0000000000000008 ep
But problem still exists, as ```ep``` is out of __bss_start/end, so assembly code can't clear its initial value

Comment: If I add -fno-common cflags, ```ep``` is put between __bss_start/end

Comment: 164008 g O .bss 0000000000000008 ep 
164000 g .bss 0000000000000000 __bss_end

Comment: It looks like a [typical default linker script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688484/actual-default-linker-script-and-settings-gcc-uses) includes `*(COMMON)` within `.bss`.  Yours doesn't, which is probably the problem.

Comment: why some variables(```ep```) go to COMMON and others go to .bss?

Comment: Thanks Nate's help, I think this problem is clear.