# C++: calling a singleton method results in "expected function body after function declarator"

Tags: c++, singleton

I am having trouble calling a member function of a singleton class. I have the following

```
// my_class.hpp

class my_class {

    friend struct singleton;

    int m_x;

    my_class(int x)
    : m_x(x) {}

    // other private constructors here

public:

    const auto& get() const {
        return m_x;
    }
};


struct singleton {

    static auto& instance() {
        static my_class x(42);
        return x;
    }
};
```

When trying to call `singleton::instance().get()` outside of main(), the compiler says "expected function body after function declarator". Here is the relevant main file:

```
singleton::instance().get();

int main() {}
```

I have found that moving the call inside main everything works fine. I have also found that storing the result outside of main also works fine, like so

```
auto v = singleton::instance().get();

int main() {}
```

What I'd like to understand is why calling it outside of main() fails and if there is a workaround that doesn't require storing the result. Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is confusing as it has nothing to do with singletons but is about statements out of functions or declarations.

Comment: Why do you think you should make the call while you don't intend to use the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is main() really start of a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783404/is-main-really-start-of-a-c-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's nothing to do with singletons.

`main` is the entrance of the program. What the compiler do before main are some declarations: variables, functions, classes. `auto v = singleton::instance().get();` is fine, it's a declaration of global variable. Obviously, the compiler take `singleton::instance().get();` as a declaraton of function, but actually it's not.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard says:

> 3.5 Program and linkage 1 A program consists of one or more translation units (Clause 2) linked together. A translation unit
>   consists of a sequence of **declarations**.

This line:

`auto v = singleton::instance().get();`

is declaration of variable, But this line

`singleton::instance().get();`

is calling methods `instance` and `get`, and compiler treats it as declaration of function which is already declared.