# C unit testing functions

Tags: c, unit-testing

In C or C++ if I have a program with the following structure:

```
..includes..
..defines..

void function_one(int i) {
    ...
}

void function_two(const char * str) {
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
}
```

Saved as `main.c/cpp`.

How can I write a new file `test.c/cpp` where I can make calls to the functions in the `main.c/cpp`?

How am I am doing it now:

Compiler flag: `-etest_main`
Files to compile: `main.c test.c`
Running test output: `Blank no errors`

My test main prints "here" but im not sure why the test executable isnt.

Comment: You might like to add a few more details to the code snippet, e.g. where's the line that would print "here"

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. And here's their Intro for Devs [doc](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/doc/introduction.html).

It's a part of the [xUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) series of test frameworks and has been around for years.

Comment: How would that solve the questioners problem having functions to be unit tested next to the main function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily test functions which reside in the same compile unit as the `main` function.

Possible solutions:

Split your `main.{c/cpp}` into two source files (compile units). One file shall only contain the `main` function, the other file all other functions. When doing unit tests, just don't link in the compile unit containing the single main function.

Alternatively, use macros to exclude the `main` function when compiling for unit tests.

Comment: Or use the loader's entry point option to start at some entry other than "main". That makes "main" just another function.

Comment: @mpez0 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3379260/2824853 that this may introduce other problems...